# When "" == s is false but "".equals( s ) is true

Tags: java, comparison, equals, equality

**EDIT**
Thanks for the prompt responses. Please see what the real question is. I have made it bold this time.

I do understand the difference between == and .equals. So, that's not my question (I actually added some context for that)

---

I'm performing the validation below for empty strings:

```
if( "" == value ) { 
    // is empty string 
}
```

In the **past** when fetching values from the db or deserializing objects from another node, this test **failed**, because the two string instances were indeed different object references, albeit they contained the same data.

So the fix for those situations was

```
if( "".equals( value ) ) {
   // which returns true for all the empty strings
}
```

I'm fine with that. That's clearly understood.

Today this happened once again, but it puzzled me because this time the application is a very small **standalone application** that doesn't use **network at all**, so no new string is fetched from the database nor deserizalized from another node.

So the question is:

## Under which **OTHER** circumstances:

```
"" == value // yields false
```

and

```
"".equals( value ) // yields true
```

For a local standalone application?

I'm pretty sure **new String()** is not being used in the code.

And the only way a string reference could be "" is because it is being assigned "" directly in the code (or that's what I thought) like in:

```
String a = "";
String b = a;

assert "" == b ; // this is true
```

Somehow (after reading the code more I have a clue) two different empty string object references were created, I would like to know **how**

More in the line of jjnguys answer:

Byte!

**EDIT: Conclusion**

I've found the reason.

After jjnguy suggestion I was able to look with different eyes to the code.

The guilty method: StringBuilder.toString()

> *A new String object is allocated and initialized to contain the character sequence currently represented by this object.*

Doh!...

```
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("h");
    b.deleteCharAt( 0 );
    System.out.println( "" == b.toString() ); // prints false
```

Mystery solved.

The code uses StringBuilder to deal with an ever growing string. It turns out that at some point somebody did:

```
 public void someAction( String string ) { 
      if( "" == string ) {
           return;
       }

       deleteBankAccount( string );
 }
```

and use

```
 someAction( myBuilder.toString() ); // bug introduced.
```

p.s. Have I read too much CodingHorror lately? Or why do I feel the need to add some funny animal pictures here?

Comment: if (value != null && value.length == 0) { ... }, and you should use equals because == for objects compares references, i.e., are they the same object. Whilst at compile time Java finds identical strings and makes them share the same reference (Strings are immutable), at run time it is easy to create empty strings that have different references.

Comment: As my answer suggests... forget what you "thought". If you mean to check if something has the same value as the empty string, then use equals. You are trying to depend on the compiler interning your strings, which Josh Bloch points out is not a tool for programmers :-). See below.

Comment: Several answers now show simple String manipulations that yield different String objects of zero length.  Networks, and goodness, have nothing to do with those answers.

Comment: (Can I just interrupt to mention `String.isEmpty` since 1.6. Thanks.)

Comment: (Oh yeah, and FindBugs will warn about this sort of thing.)

Comment: No Tom, you may not interrupt!!  (btw, I didn't know thatwas added in 1.6, thanks)

Comment: @jjunguy on Tom: I didn't knew that either..  6 revisions late but is finally there :)

Comment: Ha, agreed.  Better late than never.

Comment: ohh! Too sad, it is an instance method which means you still have to if( s != null && s.isEmpty() ) ... I rather: "".equals(ref)

Comment: That seems silly.  I really like .Net's `String.IsNullorEmpty()`.

Comment: There's also Apache Commons Lang's StringUtils, which has isBlank, isEmpty, etc. that handles the null check also.

Comment: Just use if (!"".equals(str)) ...

Comment: I wish Java had a constant for the empty string, like .Net's `String.EMPTY` constant.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
String s = "";
String s2 = someUserInputVariale.toLowercase(); // where the user entered in ""
```

Something like that would cause `s == s2` to evaluate to false.

Lots of code sill create new `Strings` without exposing the call to `new String()`.

Comment: Anytime a string is generated/created/manipulated at runtime, it has the potential to happen. I'm guessing the VM can create a new String for the string pool as it sees fit, even though for optimization, it would be better to use an existing String.

Comment: No, I like it. "We Java programmers don't even know how to SPELL optimyz... optimo... look, the JIT does it for us alright?"

Comment: haha.  The sad part is, Firefox corrects me, but I'm just too lazy to fix it.  I need auto complete for regular text.

Comment: Although not the only right answer, this lead me to find out the reason. Thanks. ..

Answer (score 22):

```
"" == value // yields false
```

and

```
"".equals( value ) // yields true
```

any time the value of the variable `value` has not been interned.  This will be the case if the value is computed at run time.  See the [JLS section 3.10.5 String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html#101084) for example code illustrating this:

> Thus, the test program consisting of the compilation unit (§7.3):
>
> ```
> package testPackage;
> class Test {
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";
>         System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");
>         System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");
>         System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " ");
>         System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo")) + " ");
>         System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");
>         System.out.println(hello == ("Hel"+lo).intern());
>     }
> }
> class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
> ```
>
> and the compilation unit:
>
> ```
> package other;
> public class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
> ```
>
> produces the output:
>
> ```
> true true true true false true
> ```
>
> This example illustrates six points:
>
> - Literal strings within the same class (§8) in the same package (§7) represent references to the same String object (§4.3.1).
> - Literal strings within different classes in the same package represent references to the same String object.
> - Literal strings within different classes in different packages likewise represent references to the same String object.
> - Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals.
> - Strings computed at run time are newly created and therefore distinct.
> - The result of explicitly interning a computed string is the same string as any pre-existing literal string with the same contents.

Answer (score 11):

If you can grab a hold of the book *Java Puzzlers* by Joshua Bloch and Neal Gafter, and look at puzzle 13, "Animal Farm"... he has great advice on this issue. I am going to copy some relevant text:

"You may be aware that compile-time constants of type `String` are *interned* [JLS 15.28]. In other words any two *constant expressions* of type `String` that designate the same character sequence are represented by identical object references... **Your code should rarely, if ever, depend on the interning of string constants.** Interning was designed solely to reduce the memory footprint of the virtual machine, not as a tool for programmers... When comparing object references, you should **use the `equals` method in preference to the `==` operator** unless you need to compare object identity rather than value."

That's from the above reference I mentioned... pages 30 - 31 in my book.

Comment: In other words... use equals because it's what you mean... and it is what you mean.

Answer (score 8):

Would you expect `"abcde".substring(1,2)` and `"zbcdefgh".substring(1,2)` to yield the same String object?

They both yield "equal" sub-strings extracted from two different Strings, but it seems quite reasonable that tehy are different objects, so == sees them as different.

Now consider when the substring has length 0,  `substring(1, 1)`. It yields a zero length String, but it's not surprising that the `"abcde".substring(1,1)` is a different object from `"zbcdefgh".substring(1,2)` and hence at least one of them is a different object from "".

Comment: I don't think this analogy really clarifies anything

Comment: I do. It says that even if there are no explicit calls to "new String", a lot of code still creates new strings... substring, toUpperCase, etc.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. clearly one would expect for it that == yields false but .equals yields true. And that's what the questioner actually asked, not "what's the diff between == and equals" what most other answered him

Comment: I've tried to spell it out a bit more. When teaching I prefer to use questions rather than answers. Guess that doesn't work quite so easily in text.

Comment: I don't understand the third paragraph though.

Comment: I don't know since when but in Java 1.5 Strings that are constructed via substring calls share the underlying char array. That means "abcde" and "abcde".substring(1,2), lets call this BC1, hold the exact same one and only "abcde" char array. Now looking at "zbcdefgh".substring(1,2) holds a references tho the shared array "zbcdefgh", lets call this BC2. Now you see that BC1 and BC2 never can be "==" but need to be completely different objects. After all BC1 contains still "abcde" and BC2 still contains "zbcdefgh".

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it while compiling the Java code to bytecode or while running the program same strings will be referenced to the same object in the most cases to save memory. So sometimes you get away with == comparisons of strings. But this is a compiler optimization you can not rely on.

But then sometimes it happens that the compiler decides to not do this optimization or there is no way for the program to see that the strings are the same and out of the sudden the check fails since you are relying on some underlying optimization voodoo that depends on implementation of the jvm you are using and so on.

So using equals is always the good thing to do. For empty strings there are other possibilities like comparing with length == 0 or if you don't care about backwards compatibility there is string.empty().

Answer (score 2):

You should try considering `String.length() == 0`.

Comment: I would suggest this too, unless the string could be null. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
if (value != null && value.length == 0) {
    // do stuff (above could be "== null ||"
}
```

You should use `equals()` because `==` for objects compares references, i.e., are they the same object. Whilst at compile time Java finds identical strings and makes them share the same reference (Strings are immutable), at runtime it is easy to create empty strings that have different references, where == fails for your typical intention of `equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this reference: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/string.html#COMPARISON at the excellent [Canadian Mind Products Java & Internet Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/jgloss.html). Worth a bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) for `String.intern()` has some good commentary on `==` vs. `.equals()`.

The documentation also clarifies that every string literal is `intern`'d.

> public String intern()
>
> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.
>
> A pool of strings, initially empty, is maintained privately by the class String.
>
> When the intern method is invoked, if
>   the pool already contains a string
>   equal to this String object as
>   determined by the equals(Object)
>   method, then the string from the pool
>   is returned. Otherwise, this String
>   object is added to the pool and a
>   reference to this String object is
>   returned.
>
> It follows that for any two strings s
>   and t, s.intern() == t.intern() is
>   true if and only if s.equals(t) is
>   true.
>
> All literal strings and string-valued
>   constant expressions are interned.
>   String literals are defined in §3.10.5
>   of the Java Language Specification
>
> Returns: a string that has the same
>   contents as this string, but is
>   guaranteed to be from a pool of unique
>   strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you use google code search, you can find lots of places where people make this same error: [google for file:.java \=\=\ \"\"](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=file%3A%5C.java+%5C%3D%5C%3D%5C+%5C%22%5C%22)  Of course, this can be a correct idiom in carefully controlled circumstances, but usually, its just a bug.

Comment: Yeah. Well, for applications using network it quite common to fail, but for self contained code it's very strange. The google query is nice!! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is dead