# Is Java's assertEquals method reliable?

Tags: java, string, junit, junit4

I know that `==` has some issues when comparing two `Strings`.  It seems that `String.equals()` is a better approach.  Well, I'm doing JUnit testing and my inclination is to use `assertEquals(str1, str2)`.  Is this a reliable way to assert two Strings contain the same content?  I would use `assertTrue(str1.equals(str2))`, but then you don't get the benefit of seeing what the expected and actual values are on failure.

On a related note, does anyone have a link to a page or thread that plainly explains the problems with `str1 == str2`?

Comment: If you are unsure, you can read the code, or the Javadoc. BTW if you want to test they are the same object you can use assertSame.

Comment: If str1 and str2 are null, assertEquals() is true, but assertTrue(str1.equals(str2)) throws an exception.  The first example will also print a useful error message such as the contents of str1 and str2, the second does not.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

You should **always** use `.equals()` when comparing `Strings` in Java.

JUnit calls the `.equals()` method to determine equality in the method `assertEquals(Object o1, Object o2)`.

So, you are definitely safe using `assertEquals(string1, string2)`. (Because `String`s are `Object`s)

[Here is a link to a great Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111296/when-s-is-false-but-equals-s-is-true) regarding some of the differences between `==` and `.equals()`.

Comment: IIRC assertEquals() succeeds if both strings are null.  If this is not what you want then call assertNotNull() as well.

Comment: additionally, if you want to test for ==, you can call assertSame()

Comment: I wouldn't say *always*; sometimes reference equality is desired, even for strings.

Answer (score 33):

`assertEquals` uses the `equals` method for comparison. There is a different assert, `assertSame`, which uses the `==` operator.

To understand why `==` shouldn't be used with strings you need to understand what `==` does: it does an identity check. That is, `a == b` checks to see if `a` and `b` refer to the *same object*. It is built into the language, and its behavior cannot be changed by different classes. The `equals` method, on the other hand, can be overridden by classes. While its default behavior (in the `Object` class) is to do an identity check using the `==` operator, many classes, including `String`, override it to instead do an "equivalence" check. In the case of `String`, instead of checking if `a` and `b` refer to the same object, `a.equals(b)` checks to see if the objects they refer to are both strings that contain exactly the same characters.

Analogy time: imagine that each `String` object is a piece of paper with something written on it. Let's say I have two pieces of paper with "Foo" written on them, and another with "Bar" written on it. If I take the first two pieces of paper and use `==` to compare them it will return `false` because it's essentially asking "are these the same piece of paper?". It doesn't need to even look at what's written on the paper. The fact that I'm giving it two pieces of paper (rather than the same one twice) means it will return `false`. If I use `equals`, however, the `equals` method will read the two pieces of paper and see that they say the same thing ("Foo"), and so it'll return `true`.

The bit that gets confusing with Strings is that the Java has a concept of "interning" Strings, and this is (effectively) automatically performed on any string literals in your code. This means that if you have two equivalent string literals in your code (even if they're in different classes) they'll actually both refer to the same `String` object. This makes the `==` operator return `true` more often than one might expect.

Comment: "That is, a == b checks to see if a and b are the same object."  Technically it checks whether a and b REFER to the same object, since a and b are references.  Unless I'm very wrong.

Comment: @user1903064 that is correct. Since non-primitive variables can only contain references in Java, it's common to skip the extra level of indirection when talking about them, but I agree that in this case being more explicit is beneficial. I've updated the answer. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 9):

In a nutshell - you can have two String objects that contain the same characters but are different objects (in different memory locations). The == operator checks to see that two references are pointing to the same object (memory location), but the equals() method checks if the characters are the same.

Usually you are interested in checking if two Strings contain the same characters, not whether they point to the same memory location.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class StringEqualityTest extends TestCase {
    public void testEquality() throws Exception {
        String a = "abcde";
        String b = new String(a);
        assertTrue(a.equals(b));
        assertFalse(a == b);
        assertEquals(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The JUnit `assertEquals(obj1, obj2)` does indeed call `obj1.equals(obj2)`.

There's also `assertSame(obj1, obj2)` which does `obj1 == obj2` (i.e., verifies that `obj1` and `obj2` are referencing the *same* instance), which is what you're trying to avoid.

So you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is used all the time for testing.  It is very likely that the testing framework uses .equals() for comparisons such as these.

Below is a link explaining the "string equality mistake".  Essentially, strings in Java are objects, and when you compare object equality, typically they are compared based on memory address, and not by content.  Because of this, two strings won't occupy the same address, even if their content is identical, so they won't match correctly, even though they look the same when printed.

http://blog.enrii.com/2006/03/15/java-string-equality-common-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

> "The `==` operator checks to see if two `Objects` are exactly the same `Object`."

http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html

`String` is an `Object` in java, so it falls into that category of comparison rules.

Comment: This did not answer the question and is kind of misleading. You can't do == on a string reliably