# Webdriver test Script Does not stop after assert failure

Tags: exception, testing, selenium, webdriver, assert

In my webdriver script I have the three methods

```
setup, test and tearDown
```

following the junit convention.

In the `test` method I have few asserts like this

```
@Test
public void testStudentHome() throws Exception {
    String classCode = "I6OWW";
    Utilities.studentSignin(driver, baseUrl);
    assertEquals(true, sth.openNotification());
    assertEquals("My Scores", sth.myScores(true));
}
```

The `sth` is the PageObject on which I am performing the tests and that I have created in the `setup` method.

I am calling all these three methods from a `main` method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        StudentHomeTest sht = new StudentHomeTest();
        try {
            sht.setup();
            sht.testStudentHome();
            sht.tearDown();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(StudentHomeTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            sht.tearDown();
        }
    }
```

Now while running the test if some assertion fails the test method should (this is what I expect) throw an exception and the `main` method should call the `tearDown` method. But this does not happen. and the browser window continues to stay there. 
I am using the netbeans ide for running the test.

Comment: JUnit's Testrunner does not need a main nor does TestNG's

Comment: Yes, that I understand. I just wanted to run 2 or 3 individual tests locally/

Comment: Use [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) instead.

Comment: ThankYouSRT, don't know how helpful this is - but I usually do a find&replace on '@Test' to '//@Test' then uncomment out the ones I want to run when running individual tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AssertionError` doesn't extend `Exception` - it's a `Throwable`.

But in any case, you should have

```
    try {
        sht.setup();
        sht.testStudentHome();
    } finally {
        sht.tearDown();
    }
```

No need for a catch block. `main` can `throw Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

> following the junit convention

If you follow the jUnit convention, then you will know that teardown methods belong in the @After method as this method will **always** run after your tests.

create a new method with the `@After` jUnit annotation.

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
  sht.tearDown();
}
```

#### Edit

You know what, I believe that you are running into a classic issue of `assertEquals` in jUnit.

Stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201927/java-is-assertequalsstring-string-reliable)...:

JUnit calls the .equals() method to determine equality in the method assertEquals(Object o1, Object o2).

So, you are definitely safe using assertEquals(string1, string2). (Because Strings are Objects)

--
Instead of using `assertEquals` on these calls, use `assertTrue()` instead.

```
assertTrue(sth.openNotification());
assertTrue("My Scores".equals(sth.myScores(true)));
```