# Selenium assertEquals behavior

Tags: java, selenium

Why does the following assertEquals() statement:

```
WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.name("send"));
Assert.assertEquals("optional", "xxxLogin", submit.getAttribute("value"));
```

give this java error result:

```
java.lang.AssertionError:  expected [xxxLogin] but found [optional]
```

The button label is Login

I was expecting to see something like expected [xxxLogin] but found [Login] (the button label).
I read that the first argument is an optional string message but it seems to be used as part of the Equals test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional string message should be the last argument:

```
Assert.assertEquals("xxxLogin", submit.getAttribute("value"), "optional");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the intended purpose of the `"optional"` string in there?

`assertEquals("xxxLogin", submit.getAttribute("value"));` should cover your needs from what I'm seeing but you can put the string in there as a third argument if needed.

An alternative could also be:

```
Assert.assertTrue(
                submit.getAttribute("value").equals("xxxLogin"),
                "Incorrect value message" //you can add the value you found to this string
        );
```

Essentially the same thing but easier to read in my opinion as you're checking for a TRUE state.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some VERY strange behaviour with using `assertEquals`... It'd be a good idea for you to use `assertTrue` or `assertFalse` as your assertion statements.  In your case, it'd be:

```
assertTrue("this test failed!", submit.getAttribute("value").equals("xxxLogin"));
```

this will no doubt work for you.

Comment: a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201927/java-is-assertequalsstring-string-reliable