# Not able to compare using assert equals in java unit test case

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm writing a unit test case, where I'm comparing one json string to expected json string, but  the assert equals is having problem.

My code is

```
output = {"id":12,"firstName":"Vengamamba","lastName":"M"}

assertEquals("{\"id\":\"12\",\"firstName\":\"Vengamamba\",\"lastName\":\"M\"}", output);
```

It says both are not equal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post some valid Java code? This rather looks like Javascript or whatever. And the _real_ error message!

Comment: what data type is output? because it is not a `String`

Answer (score 1):

They does not looks equals to me neither since you've used \"12\" when it's 12 without quotes in the original.

The assertEquals should works fine

[Java: Is assertEquals(String, String) reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201927/java-is-assertequalsstring-string-reliable)