# JUnit asserting two Strings whether they're equal or not

Tags: java, junit, outputstream

So I looked up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201927/java-is-assertequalsstring-string-reliable) and tried it, but with no success.

My code should be testing if the method is correctly outputing the text onto the console by reading it back in using `Streams`.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream myStream = new PrintStream(outStream);
    System.setOut(myStream);
    o.doSomething(); //printing out Hi
    System.out.flush();
    System.setOut(savedOldStream);//setting it back to System.out
    assertEquals(outStream.toString(),"Hi");
```

but everytime I run JUnit it fails.
I also tried: `assertTrue(outStream.toString().equals("Hi"));` but this didn't work either.

This is the doSomething() method:

```
public void doSomething () {
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*didn't work*"?  What actually happens? Are you getting any errors or just a failed assertion?

Comment: There is no need to re-assign the `System.out` to test this. You can pass the `ByteArrayOutputStream` to the `doSomething()` method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PrintStream#println(String str)` appends a newline at the end of the string. Therefore, your assertion should trim down the additional line:

```
assertEquals(outStream.toString().trim(),"Hi");
```

Comment: Writing to `System.out` will not write anything in the `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Thank you very much! SO using System.out.print would also fix the problem?

Comment: @Jesper The OP has re-assigned `System.out`.

Comment: @NhatNienne Yes using `print` would avoid the newline.

Comment: Agree. For this case, the OP could do as you suggested: passing the output stream as param.