# JUnit Assertion error with identical strings

Tags: java, testing, junit, dropwizard, metrics

I'm trying to make a test-case to check for the Dropwizard Metric Meter name:
Here's the code:

```
@Test
public void getMeterName(){
  String metricsPrefix = "com.company.team";
  String tagSupplied = "tenant.db.table";
  String expectedMeterName = "com.company.team.tenant.db.table";

  assertSame(expectedMeterName,MetricRegistry.name(metricsPrefix,tagSupplied));
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected same:<com.company.team.tenant.db.table> was not:<com.company.team.tenant.db.table>
Expected :com.company.team.tenant.db.table
Actual   :com.company.team.tenant.db.table
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

The strings that you are testing are equal but not the same object.

You are using `assertSame` where you should be using `assertEquals`.

This is analogous to the mistake of using `==` to compare strings.

(See also: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java))

Answer (score 0):

**Use assertEquals()** instead of assertSame() because you can't use assertSame() with Strings.
.Refer this [JUnit asserting two Strings whether they're equal or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579868/junit-asserting-two-strings-whether-theyre-equal-or-not)