# Why are there brackets after my String's value?

Tags: java, junit

I have a test like this:

```
String dir = "/foo";
String fileName = "hello.txt";
String pathString = dir + "/" + fileName;
String text = "hello world!";
MyTask task = new MyTask();

FileSystem fs = Jimfs.newFileSystem(Configuration.unix());

Path foo = fs.getPath(dir);
Files.createDirectory(foo);
Path hello = foo.resolve(fileName);
Files.write(hello, ImmutableList.of(text), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

task.setFileSystem(fs);
String fileValue = task.readFile(pathString);

// Doing this just shows "fail whale: hello world!"
// fail("fail whale: " + fileValue); 

// Failure from here adds brackets
assertEquals(text, fileValue);
```

I get a failure like this:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<hello world![]> but was:<hello world![
]>
```

If I reverse the arguments, I can see that `readFile` is definitely creating that new line, and it's not just my terminal truncating.

I have no idea why JUnit is showing brackets after my string at all, and am even more confused as to why a space would get added.

`readFile` is simply this:

```
public String readFile(String path) {
  try {
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(fs.getPath(path)));
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
  }
}
```

[Java: Is assertEquals(String, String) reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201927/java-is-assertequalsstring-string-reliable) makes reference of the `String` being an `Object`, but if that is the case, an the brackets just imply `Object`, still really confused about that new line.

Comment: `Files.write` writes end of line (\n) symbol at the end of the line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JUnit `assertEquals` method puts square brackets around the part of the string where the difference occurred, to help highlight the problem for you. (Play around with `assertEquals("abcde", "acedc")` or the like to see it on a more intuitive example.)

In this case, it shows that one string has nothing after it, while another string has a newline at the end of it.

The [`Files.write` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) states:

> Each line is a char sequence and is written to the file in sequence with each line terminated by the platform's line separator, as defined by the system property `line.separator`.

Comment: Also, it's funny my first time using JUnit, I make a string error that is the end of the line like that, which made it look like another thing altogether :P

Answer (score 3):

The brackets are meant to highlight where the strings are different.

In your case, there it is highlighting an unexpected newline at the end of your actual result.