# printing the address of the string instances

Tags: java, string

```
package com.testProject;
public class JavaSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String myString1 = new String("Sample1");
        System.out.println(myString1);
        String myString2 = new String("Sample2");
        System.out.println(myString2);
    }
}
```

in the above piece of code how to print the address of these Strings which i created "Sample1" and "Sample2", i need to print the memory location of the String object myString1 and myString2

Comment: I guess you can't do that in Java, no pointers.

Comment: This may be of assistance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060215/how-can-i-get-the-memory-location-of-a-object-in-java

Comment: Actually, you can, though its neither recommended, nor straightforward, see my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean "address" as this:

```
System.out.println(new Object());
```

java.lang.Object@**31ec0130**

then you can just do,

```
String s = new String("one");
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(s.hashCode()));
```

1ae66

Since what you think is the "address" is just the hashCode() converted to hex string.

---

> **Side Note**
>   This answer was historically accepted as correct and will only work for classes that didn't override the `hashCode()`
>   method, but **(as mentioned in comments) it will not work for `String`
>   classes** since they override the `hashCode()` method. Readers looking for up-to-date
>   information on the topic of this question should first go through all
>   the comments/discussion on this answer and should consult further
>   resources, or ask a new question citing this question and answer and
>   explicitly asking for new information on things that have changed
>   since they were written.

Comment: Every object has a hashCode() method. A hashcode is an int value for an object, so that the object can be used in Collection classes that use hashing, including Hashtable, HashMap, and HashSet.

Comment: I don't think hashcode is related to the actual memory address of the object. :)

Comment: hashcode is a mathematically calculated value of the content of variable. Its not the address in any way.

Comment: @renz This works for any class that didn't override the hashcode method and uses the default implementation of the Object class, which prints the address in the memory. The String class overrides the hashcode method and hence doesnot return the memory location of the String.

Comment: This is wrong, as the comment above me said. Ence my downvote

Comment: @renz Can you please provide the code for converting this "@ebec264" memory address to string ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @renz I don't think so it's address "Integer.toHexString(s.hashCode())"

Comment: <code>
String str = "hello"; // it's in string constant pool

String str1 = new String("hello"); // in heap not in string constant pool - right

System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(str.hashCode()));

System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(str1.hashCode()));
// How the memory location for both be same
<code>

Comment: The "hashCode" method is overridden in the String class.  It does NOT return anything like the "address" of anything in memory.  The value it returns is a function of the characters in the string.

Here is the source code that does this:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29

Comment: This is not the way to find the actual address. To check it do `String s = "abc"; String s2 = new String("abc"); System.out.println(s1 == s2)` This will print `false` meaning that both the objects are different. But if you do your operations, you'll find that you're getting "same" address.

Comment: Hello just consider this scenario String s1="abc"; and String s2= new  String("abc"); then the above approach returns the same value which is not valid As the address should be different but hash can be same.

Comment: This is truly wrong. the actual memory of the String Object and the result of hashCode() is different from each other.

Answer (score 20):

it seems like you all are INCORRECT! 
Ill try to explain :

```
        String s = new String("hi Mr. Buddy");
//        s = = "hi Mr. Buddy"; //is false
//        s.equals("hi Mr. Buddy"); //is true
        System.out.println( s.hashCode() );
        System.out.println( "hi Mr. Buddy".hashCode() );

        System.out.println( "hi Mr. Buddy" == s );

        System.out.println( "hi Mr. Buddy" );
```

result of this in my case :

```
1372880496
1372880496
false
hi Mr. Buddy
```

As we see the hashCode() are same, but String has differet addresses (bcs "hi Mr. Buddy" == s >>== false ) 
? what do you think ?

I found :

```
System.out.println( "s=" + System.identityHashCode( s ) );
System.out.println( "..=" + System.identityHashCode( "hi Mr. Buddy" ) );
```

the result is:

```
s=733003674
..=1626549726
```

Comment: The explaining of that is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396927/how-to-print-the-address-of-an-object-if-you-have-redefined-tostring-method

Answer (score 14):

As pointed out my comment, this isn't recommended practise, but since you asked...

```
private static Unsafe unsafe;

static
{
    try
    {
        Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        unsafe = (Unsafe)field.get(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static long addressOf(Object o)
throws Exception
{
    Object[] array = new Object[] {o};

    long baseOffset = unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(Object[].class);
    int addressSize = unsafe.addressSize();
    long objectAddress;
    switch (addressSize)
    {
        case 4:
            objectAddress = unsafe.getInt(array, baseOffset);
            break;
        case 8:
            objectAddress = unsafe.getLong(array, baseOffset);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error("unsupported address size: " + addressSize);
    }       

    return(objectAddress);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Memory addresses aren't generally available through the Java language, but `System.identityHashCode(myString1)` might be close enough, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

I think answer by @AnNik should be considered as correct answer. Below is the comparison,

```
   String s1= "abc";
    String s2 = new String("abc");
    String s3= "abc";


    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(s1.hashCode()));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(s2.hashCode()));
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(s3.hashCode()));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s1));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s2));
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(s3));
```

Output:

```
17862
17862
17862
356573597
1735600054
356573597
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cannot. JVM handles the memory and the gc can shift the data around when it sees fit.

So there is no "real" concept of a memory address within Java(it only is the concern of the JVM)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use printf with %b:

```
String s= new String("Hello");
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(s.hashCode()));
System.out.printf("address of the reference variable s holding string \"%s\" is %h%n", s,s);
```

Answer (score -1):

simply right ur string name followed by this code:

```
string object.getClass.getName()+'@'+Integer.toHexString(string boject.hashCode());
```

example:

```
String str=new String("Hello");
System.out.println(str.getClass.getName+'@'+Integer.toHexString(str.hashCode());
```