# How to print the address of an object if you have redefined toString method

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to Java. Now I'm studying equals and == and redefinition of equals and toString.

I would like to use both the toString method that I have redefied and the default method that is inherited from the Object class.

I failed to use that super modificator to reach that method.

This is for educational purposes only. What I would like to get is more clear if you will have a look at the comments in my code.

Could you help me here?

My code is:

```
public class EqualTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Employee alice1 = new Employee("Alice Adams", 75000, 1987, 12, 15);
            //System.out.super.println(alice1);

        Employee alice2 = alice1;
            //System.out.super.println(alice2);

        Employee alice3 = new Employee("Alice Adams", 75000, 1987, 12, 15);
            //System.out.super.println(alice3);

        System.out.println("alice1==alice2: " + (alice1==alice2));
        System.out.println("alice1 == alice3: " + (alice1==alice3));
        System.out.println("alice1.equals(alice3): " + alice1.equals(alice3));
    }
}

class Employee{
...
    public String toString(){
        return getClass().getName() + "[name = " + name + 
            ", salary=" + salary + ", hireDay=" + hireDay + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Firstly it's not called redefining it's called overriding

Comment: But the default implementation does not return the adress of the object. It returns the class name and the hashCode of that object. From the documentation of java.lang.Object: 'getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())'

Comment: Well, yes. But the hash code is the address. Look at the documentation for Object hashCode: This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language. So, the hash code is just the same hex number representing the address. But its converted into decimal.

Comment: Well, no. It *can* be the address, but there is no guaranteee. You were therefore never able to print the address reliably in the first place, regardless of whether or not you overrode `toString().` But I don't see any requirement here to actually get the address at all, just the original result of `toString(),` which is available via `super.toString()`, despite your unspecified 'failure'. Your actual question remains unclear.

Comment: Why not. It is the address. At a given time it is the address represented as int. As we are are talking about more or less static environment, the address will not change. I mean, that in such a simple program, the garbage collector didn't touch the heap. So, why is it not the address in this case?

Comment: @Kifsif  Saying `It is the address` is plain wrong. It **may be** the address (and in most cases, but not all, it probably is).
Ie, if you rely on `hashCode()` for getting the address of objects it may work in some cases, but in other cases it may fail.
Eg, it'd be possible according to the specs that some JVM keeps a completely random number as hashcode stored for each object. In reality, this probably wouldn't be the case, since it would entail unecessary storage overhead.
Anyways, in Java you typically shouldn't be concerned with at what memory addresses objects are located. Java is not C.

Comment: To get addresses, use Unsafe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't print the address of an object in pure Java.  The number that looks like an object address in the String produced by `Object.toString()` is the object's "identity hashcode".  It may or may not be related to the object's current address:

- The specs *do not say* how the identity hashcode number is calculated.  It is deliberately left unspecified.
- Since the number is a hashcode, it *cannot* change.  So even though it is (typically) related to an object address, that will be the object's address *at the time when the hashcode was first accessed*.  This could be different to its current address, and it *will* be different if the GC has moved the object since the first time the object's identity hashcode was observed.
- On a 64bit JVM (with a large enough heap size / not using compressed oops) addresses won't fit into an identity hashcode number which is returned as an `int`.

Anyhow, the way to get this number is to call [`System.identityHashCode(obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-).

---

If you really want an object's *current* address, you can get it using JNI and a native method (and some abstraction breaking), or by using methods in the `Unsafe` class (see [How can I get the memory location of a object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060215)).  But beware that both of these approaches are non-portable.  Also, the object addresses that they give you are liable to "break" when the GC moves the object which renders them problematic for many (probably most) potential use-cases.

---

For the doubters, this is what the Java 10 javadocs say on the "hashcode != address" point:

> "(The hashCode **may or may not** be implemented as **some function of** an object's memory address **at some point in time**.)"

Emphasis added.  Indeed, with recent JVMs, the default algorithm does NOT derive the hashCode from a memory address at all.  It has been that way since at least Java 7.

You can confirm this by including `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`  in the command line options to find out what the `hashcode` flag defaults to, and then looking at the OpenJDK source code to see what it means.  (The code is in the "vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp" file in some versions, but YMMV.)

Answer (score 22):

If you want to achieve sort-of default `toString()` behavior, you can make use of `System.identityHashCode()` method. Default `toString()` will then look like this:

```
public String toString(Object o) {
    return o.getClass().getName() + "@" + 
           Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(o));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call super() method to execute the corresponding superclass method.

```
class Employee{
...
    public String toString(){
         String s = super.toString();
        return getClass().getName() + "[name = " + name + 
            ", salary=" + salary + ", hireDay=" + hireDay + "]" + s;
    }
```

toString() in Object class is as follows

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Comment: This won't work if this class extends a superclass that overrides `toString()`.  (And you call `toString()` further up the inheritance hierarchy ...).  There is a better way than this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an in-depth answer about overriding equals and hashcode

[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

The key point being
The relation between the two methods is:

Whenever a.equals(b), then a.hashCode() must be same as b.hashCode().

Answer (score 0):

You may create another method inside your Employee class to use super toString method.

See example:

```
public class Employee {
    public String toString() {
        return "MyToStringMethod";
    }

    public String superToString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee b = new Employee();
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(b.superToString());
    }
}
```

or combine both in one method:

```
public class Employee {
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " MyToStringMethod";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee b = new Employee();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```