# Difference in the following declarations

Tags: java, string, declaration, string-concatenation

I am unable to recognize the difference in the following declarations of Strings in Java.

Suppose I am having two string

```
String str1="one";
String str2="two";
```

What is the difference between

```
String str3=new String(str1+str2);
```

and

```
String str3=str1+str2;
```

In both the above declarations, the content of `str3` will be `onetwo`.

Suppose I create a new string

```
String str4="onetwo";
```

Then in none of the above declarations,

```
if(str4==str3) {
    System.out.println("This is not executed");
}
```

Why are `str3` and `str4` not referring to the same object?

Comment: Don't use `==` to compare strings

Comment: @Apurva : I want to compare objects, not contents of strings. I want to know where `str4` and `str3` are referring

Comment: this is actually comparing the reference that is if the str4 and str3 will points to the same location then it will equals which here is at different location.... instead use equal method of string

Comment: @Iftikhar Why and where str3 and str4 are referring to different location

Comment: you can't print the address of an object in pure Java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396927/how-to-print-the-address-of-an-object-if-you-have-redefined-tostring-method

Comment: `Why and where str3 and str4 are referring to different location` Why do you think they should have the same reference?

Comment: @Tom because `String str3=str1+str2` should have been a interned string and `str4` should refer to the same location as `str3`

Comment: @kevingomes "*because `String str3=str1+str2` should have been a interned*" no, compiler can't be sure of values of non-final variables so it can't concatenate them at compilation time like it can do in case of `"foo"+"bar"` and intern it. It will compile it into `new StringBuilder(str1).append(str2).toString()` and this result will not be interned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str1 + str2` for non-compilation-constant strings will be compiled into
`new StringBuilder(str1).append(str2).toString()`. This result will not be put, or taken from string pool (where interned strings go).

It is different story in case of `"foo"+"bar"` where compiler knows which values he works with, so he can concatenate this string once to avoid it at runtime. Such string literal will also be interned.

So `String str3 = str1+str2;` is same as

```
String str3 = new StringBuilder(str1).append(str2).toString();
```

and `String str3 = new String(str1+str2);` is same as

```
String str3 = new String(new StringBuilder(str1).append(str2).toString());
```

Again, strings produced as result of method (like `substring`, `replace`, `toString`) are not interned.
This means you are comparing two different instances (which store same characters) and that is why `==` returns `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Java does not have memory of "how this variable got the value", therefore it really does not matter which method you use, if the result is same.

About comparing, if you compare strings with `==`, you are comparing address of objects in memory, because String is not primitive data type, not values. You have to use `if(str4.equals(str3))`

Comment: I want to compare the address of the objects only.Wht str3 and str4 are having different references

Comment: It matters which method we use

Comment: @kevingomes - google : java tutorial. Actually you want to compare values, not address in memory, in your example. If your wife gives life to twins, they can look same, but they are two different instances. If you want to know, if they are look same, you use "equals", if you want to know, if they are same person, you use "==".

Answer (score 3):

Because `String`s in Java are immutable the compiler will optimize and reuse `String` literals. Thus

```
String s1 = "one";
String s2 = "one";
s1 == s2; //true because the compiler will reuse the same String (with the same memory address) for the same string literal
s1 == "o" + "ne"; //true because "Strings computed by constant expressions are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals"
s3 = "o";
s1 == s3 + "ne"; //false because the second string is created a run time and is therefore newly created
```

for a reference see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

Comment: You used the word `immutable`

Comment: `may be true as the compiler may ...`? This will _always_ be true.

Comment: I believe that any compiler _will_ do this, so it will likely be true in practice. However I don't think this behavior is actually defined in the language standard so I didn't want to say that it would always be true as a valid compiler could have different behavior.

Comment: Interning Strings has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: You're right, string literals will always be interned http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5 fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are kind of tricky, because there is some effort to share their representation. Plus they're immutable.
**The short answer is: unless you're really working in a low level, you should never compare strings using "==".** 
Even if it works for you, it will be a nightmare for your teammates to maintain.

For a longer answer and a bit of amusement, try the following:

```
String s1= "a" + "b";
String s2= "a" + "b";
String s3=new String("a"+"b");

System.out.println(s1==s2);
System.out.println(s3==s2);
```

You'll notice that s1==s2 due to the compiler's effort to share. 
However s2 != s3 because you've explicitly asked for a new string.
You're not likely to do anything very smart with it, because it's immutable.