# Java - How do you find the memory location of each element in a linkedlist?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodereference

There's an interview question that asks you to determine if two linkedlists intersect with each other. So we're required to access the memory location of each node/element of the linkedlist since we're comparing the memory location of each node.

Usually we compare the value of each element. However I'm not sure how to access the memory location of such linkedlist element?

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: there's `==` operator for that (for reference types)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351555/printing-the-address-of-the-string-instances looking like this ?

Comment: Were you explicitly told that you need to consider the memory locations, or did you decide that requirement by yourself?

Comment: You don't need the memory location, only the reference values.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes the hints say find and compare the reference values. But I'm not entirely sure what this reference value mean or how to find it? Thanks!

Comment: In java you have two types of fields, primitives like `1` and `2.34` and references.  If it's not a primitive value is a reference.  You can compare them using `==`