# How to obtain Java "object" address in Java Native Interface

Tags: java, memory, java-native-interface

Is it possible to get the address of a Java object in a JNI method? Or by any other method.

If it is not possible to get real address of an object, then is there a way to determine the memory layout of a data structure?

---

(This is just an example, description of my question is above this line.)

For instance, I have an array(or any other kinds of container, e.g. ArrayList, LinkedList etc.) of "objects", I want to know how these "objects" (not the references within the container) are allocated on the heap, they may not be allocated continuously, or even randomly ordered. So can I get any information about that?

---

Edit:
Here is another thought, is there any other Java virtual machine can handle this kind of low level thing? For example, Jikes, or even Dalvik.

Comment: Arrays are allocated contiguously. It's required by the [JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.anewarray). Not a  real question.

Comment: Objects are references right? What if I assign each element within an array with newly newed objects with arbitrary order? Besides, array is  just an example, what if I use a ArrayList or LinkedList.

Comment: "What if" still makes it a too ambiguous question.

Comment: The question is *not* ambiguous - to someone who understands JNI, it's quite clear.

Comment: @dawnstar Arrays are still allocated contiguously. The objects referred to by the array elements aren't. Your purpose remains obscure.

Comment: @EJP I think my purpose is clear, I want to get the memory layout of these "objects" of an array of "objects". Like you said, their references may allocated contiguously, but I want to know how the objects allocated on the heap.

Comment: @Jesse Forget about the "what if", those are only explanations to let people understand easily. My question is simply and easy, as in the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html. It provides some low-level operations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060215/how-can-i-get-the-memory-location-of-a-object-in-java - This may help with using `Unsafe` for this purpose.

Comment: @prunge This actually can do the trick, but every time I compile it, the warning says that "the Unsafe may be removed in the future" is really disturbing. Any way, this seems to be the only way to do the trick without touching the source code in the OpenJDK.