# Unsafe's method compareAndSwapObject mechanism

Tags: java, concurrency, jvm, unsafe

today I read AQS source code.I found some confuse place about `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer#addWaiter`method:

```java
    private Node addWaiter(Node mode) {
        Node node = new Node(Thread.currentThread(), mode);
        // Try the fast path of enq; backup to full enq on failure
        Node pred = tail;
        if (pred != null) {
            node.prev = pred;
            if (compareAndSetTail(pred, node)) {
                pred.next = node;
                return node;
            }
        }
        enq(node);
        return node;
    }
```

does `pred` value changed after `compareAndSetTail` in second if statement?

so I make a test for it. but it make me more and more confuse.

I found `compareAndSetTail` call `compareAndSwapObject` finally.

so I test `compareAndSwapObject` in Unsafe Package.

this is my test code

```java
    private static final long nameOffset;
    private String name="init-name";
    static Unsafe unsafe = reflectGetUnsafe();
    static {
        try {
            nameOffset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset
                    (AQSTest.class.getDeclaredField("name"));
        } catch (Exception ex) { throw new Error(ex); }
    }
    private static Unsafe reflectGetUnsafe() {
        try {
            Field field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return (Unsafe) field.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testUnsafe() {
        String preName = name;
        unsafe.compareAndSwapObject(this, nameOffset, preName, "new-name");
        System.out.println("preName:" + preName);
        System.out.println("name:" + name);
    }
```

and its output is:

```
preName:init-name
name:new-name
```

Why did `name` change, but `preName` keep the original value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compareAndSwapObject()` does not work the way you (probably) expect. This could be so due to slightly confusing name.

It does not actually *swaps* the objects. It changes only `name` by checking if `name == preName`, and if so, it just updates its value. There's always *one* target field to be updated, not two.

BTW, [here](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html) are good unofficial docs for `Unsafe` class. You can get some useful information from it.

Comment: Hmm, the starting point was a method named `compareAndSetTail`. I can’t retrace why the OP ever came to the conclusion that it changes the `pred` argument. The method name is not suggesting that. Besides that, it’s more useful to point at the official API like `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` or Java 9‘s `VarHandle`, which follow the same principle, but have value for future software development.

Comment: @Holger, my guess is that the OP was confused by `compareAndSwapObject()`method thinking it swaps objects, which led him to conclusion that `compareAndSetTail()` swaps objects as well.

Comment: thanks, i do misunderstand `compareAndSwapObject()` params means. It do change `nameOffset`'s value after check `preName'=='nameOffset`'s value and I found `preName` obj has different **offset** with `name` through print them offset like this:```nameOffset:14 preNameOffset:16```. it lead another question [String s1==String s2(true) but FieldOffset is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859969/string-s1-string-s2-true-but-fieldoffset-is-different?rq=1)