# Implementation of object cache in Neo4j 3.2.3

Tags: neo4j

I have read this post ["Understanding of Neo4j object cache"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612552/understanding-of-neo4j-object-cache), but can't find 'NodeImpl' any more in the source code of **Neo4j 3.2.3**.

I tried some code to track down to the implementation of Neo4j, but fail to find access to any cache other than page cache.  I tried to get property of same node twice, expect to hit the cache when shoot the second query.

```
            Node n = db.getNodeById(0);
            n.getProperty("name");
            String name = (String) n.getProperty("name");
            System.out.println("name: " + name);
```

There is a lot of 'InstanceCache' inside 'StoreStatement', but as the comment implies, instance cache is used for single object, not used for connection between node and relationship as described here in ['An overview of Neo4j Internals'](https://www.slideshare.net/thobe/an-overview-of-neo4j-internals).

My question is:

1. What's the implementation of object cache inside neo4j 3.2.3 ?
2. Is there anything newer for internals of neo4j ? The slide I got is published 6 year ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Object Cache** doesn't exist anymore in Neo4j (since version 3.0 from what I remember), there is only the **page cache**.

Slides from Tobias that explain the graph storage are still correct.

Comment: i saw that there is a field named 'needsCacheInvalidation' in TransactionApplicationMode, so that's for the purpose to invalidate page cache ?

Comment: Do the details of the object cache apply to the page cache? I.e. are the nodes & relationship records transformed as shown on the slides or are they nowadays just cached as they are on disk?

Comment: as they are  on the disk