# how to view the the address of object of String class?

Tags: java, string

described above. for example.

```
String s = "abc";
System.out.println(s); // this method will output the string, not the address
```

so how to view the address, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the memory location of a object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060215/how-can-i-get-the-memory-location-of-a-object-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Java has no concept of "address", so it is impossible to get the address of any object, including strings.

Comment: thanks. if execute `System.out.println(new int[] {1, 2, 3});`, it outputs `[I@621be5d1`. can the String class output it like that format?

Answer (score 0):

if u want an answer as u mentioned in the comment, Actually there is a way to do it that way.

```
String s = new String("abc");
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(s.hashCode()));
```

this will return

```
1ae66
```

This answer was historically accepted as correct and will only work for classes that didn't override the hashCode() method

Comment: System.identityHashCode() gives you always the original implementation :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-