# What is the meaning of a String ID in Java?

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why equals() method when we have == operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772763/why-equals-method-when-we-have-operator)

When I tried executing the code in Java, it gave me 2 different outputs

```
String txt1="Hello";
String txt2="Hello";
System.out.println((boolean)txt1==txt2);

String txt1=new String("Hello");
String txt2=new String("Hello");
System.out.println((boolean)txt1==txt2);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390703/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-expression-new-string-in-java this will be helpful.

Comment: also no need to cast result of `==` operator to `boolean`

Answer (score 8):

Strings are objects. `==` compares object references, not the content of the strings. To do that, use the `String#equals` method.

In your first example, `txt1` and `txt2` are two variables pointing to the *same* `String` object. So they're `==` to each other.

In your second example, `txt1` and `txt2` are pointing to two *different* `String` objects (which have the same sequence of characters), and so they aren't `==` to each other.

---

Separately: There's almost never any point to writing `new String("string literal")`. If you don't know specifically a really, really good reason to do it, don't. There are only a couple of very, very, *very* unusual situations where you might do that, which relate to interacting with low-level stuff. Not in normal, portable Java code.

There is *occasionally* a reason to use `new String(String)` (not a string *literal*, but an instance you got from somewhere else, like `substring`). See [this article](http://kjetilod.blogspot.in/2008/09/string-constructor-considered-useless.html) for more on that (thanks [Rp-](http://kjetilod.blogspot.in/2008/09/string-constructor-considered-useless.html)).

Comment: then why would the first one return true?

Comment: @user1247347: Because `txt1` and `txt2` are variables pointing to the *same* object. (Click refresh to make sure you're reading my complete answer, I realized that my first quick answer might not have been sufficient and added to it.)

Comment: http://kjetilod.blogspot.in/2008/09/string-constructor-considered-useless.html this blog explains the rare usages of `new String(someStr);`.. Follow the comments as well.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Indeed, I've clarified it.

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator will check for reference equality, that is, will return `true` if the two argument `String`s are the same instance.

Whenever a `String` literal (for instance `"Hello"`) occurs in a class, a `String` instance is *interned* (kind of stored in an internal cache so it can be reused).

After doing `String txt1="Hello"`, `txt1` will be very same reference of the interned `String`. So,

```
String txt1="Hello";
String txt2="Hello";
```

Results in `txt1` and `txt2` being the same instance, that is, the interned one.

When you're doing `String txt1=new String("Hello")`, it's calling the `String` constructor with the interned instance as an argument (kind of a copy constructor). So, `txt1` will be a **new** `String` instance holding the same value as the interned instance, and the `==` operator will return `false`.

More information on the subject can be found in the  [3.10.5. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) section of the JLS.

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class String
>   (§4.3.1, §4.3.3).
>
> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class
>   String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings
>   that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned"
>   so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

The following question's answer explain [When are Java Strings interned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3451145/851811). The following link elaborates on the subject: [String Equality and Interning](http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/).

As a side note, remember to use `equals()` in order to perform String comparisons based on their contents.

Comment: When I tried debugging them, txt1 and txt2 in the second case had different IDs. So what are these IDs? Are they some kind of value given to the object based on the memory location?

Comment: That's right, it's the value that identifies the instance. They're effectively differents `String` instances holding the same value, so `==` returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Java, where possible, tries to "share" strings to safe space.

```
String txt1="Hello";
String txt2="Hello";
```

are two references to the same Object ("Hello")

```
String txt1=new String("Hello");
String txt2=new String("Hello");
```

Are two references to two different instances, each initialised by copy.

If you compare Strings, always use "equals()" because otherwise results are hard to predict.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare references then use `==` operator.

If you want to compare contents of two strings use `equals` method.

Comment: '==', not '='. '=' is an assignment

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
String txt1="Hello";
String txt2="Hello";
System.out.println(txt1.hashCode());
System.out.println(txt2.hashCode());
System.out.println((boolean)txt1==txt2);


String txt1=new String("Hello");
String txt2=new String("Hello");
System.out.println(txt1.hashCode());
System.out.println(txt2.hashCode());
System.out.println((boolean)txt1==txt2);
```

You can get how java handles internally.

Comment: Well the hashCode for both the cases were same!

Comment: @user1247347 yes. might be String() objects converted as literals in this case. When we create it in runtime will get different one.