# Strange behavior with string interning in Java

Tags: java, string

There is code as following:

```
String s = new String("1");
s.intern();
String s2 = "1";
System.out.println(s == s2);

String s3 = new String("1")+new String("1");
s3.intern();
String s4 = "11";
System.out.println(s3 == s4);
```

Output of the code above is:

```
false
true
```

I know that `s` and `s2` are different objects, so the result evaluates to  false, but the second result evaluates to true. Can anyone tell me the difference?

Comment: You may wish to refer [this](http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/)

Comment: Note that calling `s3.intern()` after initializing `s4` changes the output to `false`. This *seems* to indicate that the literal `"11"` is only retrieved from the pool as the line is executed, which isn't how I understood string literal interning to work.

Comment: Interestingly, changing to `s = new String("11")` and `s2 = "11"` all of the sudden makes the comparison `s3 == s4` evaluate to false.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen That's essentially the same observation I made. You just moved the literal higher up.

Comment: @PratikAmbani That looks like the correct answer to me. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor It's not an answer at all, it's just a link to an article.

Comment: For users that do not have enough reputation to see the graveyard of deleted answers to this question – if you're planning to write an answer that  a) outlines the fundamentals of string interning in Java, or b) suggests that the result of `String.intern()` should be assigned back to the variable: don't bother. The real question is why the behavior in the two cases (`s == s2` vs `s3 == s4`) is different.

Comment: what's the compiled bytecode look like?

Comment: I wonder how this can be unclear at all, even to gold badge owners. It is so obivous that the literal `"1"` has to be loaded when using `new String("1")` and that the String `"11"` will be added to pool using `s3.intern();` and then fetched for `String s4 = "11";`. This is basic stuff like 1+1=2.

Answer (score 23):

Here's what's happening:

---

### Example 1

```
String s1 = new String("1"); 
s1.intern();
String s2 = "1";
```

1. The string literal `"1"` (passed into the `String` constructor) is interned at address **A**.
   String `s1` is created at address **B** because it is not a literal or constant expression.
2. The call to `intern()` has no effect. String `"1"` is already interned, and the result of the operation is not assigned back to `s1`.
3. String `s2` with value `"1"` is retrieved from the string pool, so points to address **A**.

**Result: Strings `s1` and `s2` point to *different* addresses.**

---

### Example 2

```
String s3 = new String("1") + new String("1");
s3.intern();
String s4 = "11";
```

1. String `s3` is created at address **C**.
2. The call to `intern()` adds the string with value `"11"` at address **C** to the string pool.
3. String `s4` with value `"11"` is retrieved from the string pool, so points to address **C**.

**Result: Strings `s3` and `s4` point to the *same* address.**

---

### Summary

String `"1"` is interned before the call to `intern()` is made, by virtue of its presence in the `s1 = new String("1")` constructor call.

Changing that constructor call to `s1 = new String(new char[]{'1'})` will make the comparison of `s1 == s2` evaluate to true because both will now refer to the string that was explicitly interned by calling `s1.intern()`.

*(I used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7060500/3558960) to get information about the strings' memory locations.)*

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now, but it requires very careful reading. Note that the observed behavior changes if any other code has already put `"11"` into the interned string pool before.

Comment: @RolandIllig  Indeed, I noted that in the comments to the question.

Comment: The steps in your breakdown can be deduced from the output, as I [commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42824821/java-please-help-me-to-understand-these-code-result#comment72761604_42824821) earlier. I'm much more interested in seeing where it's documented, if indeed it is.

Comment: @shmosel What would you like to see documented? That the mere use of a string literal (without assigning it) is enough to have it interned in the string pool?

Comment: That string literals aren't interned until they're used.

Comment: @shmosel Define "used".

Comment: Referenced, assigned, `s4 = "11"`

Comment: @shmosel Well, that's exactly my point. They *are* interned without being referenced or assigned. If, for example, you call `System.out.println("a")`, the string `"a"` will be interned`

Comment: I meant "used" the same way you did. My point is I would have expected `"a"` to be interned long before that statement executes, possibly at class load. I might have been entirely wrong, but it would be nice to see a source one way or another.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the string that is kept in the pool is the first one of this value that is interned.

Comment: @MauricePerry that is indeed what I observed from inspecting the memory addresses.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe you should stress somewhere that this is (also) why it is a bad idea to use the `String` constructor that takes a string literal (like Effective Java warns).

Comment: @shmosel The [JVM Specification, Chapter 5.1 The Run-Time Constant Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.1) looks like a good source. There is no obvious single sentence that explains it all, so it's probably a combination of five of the sentences in that chapter that will form the proof.

Answer (score 12):

**For the scenario 1:**

```
String s = new String("1");
s.intern();
String s2 = "1";
System.out.println(s == s2);
```

with **bytecode**:

```
   0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/String
   3: dup
   4: ldc           #3                  // String 1
   6: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   9: astore_1
  10: aload_1
  11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/String.intern:()Ljava/lang/String;
  14: pop
  15: ldc           #3                  // String 1
```

for `String s = new String("1");` it will create a new `String` object, it will have a new address with **"1"** that it is already in **String Pool**:

`ldc           #3                  // String 1`

and for `s2`, as the bytecode:

`15: ldc           #3                  // String 1`

`s2` is pointing to **String Pool** variable: `"1"`, so `s` and `s2` have the different address and  result is `false`.

**For the scenario 2:**

```
String s3 = new String("1")+new String("1");
s3.intern();
String s4 = "11";
System.out.println(s3 == s4);
```

with **bytecode**:

```
   0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3: dup
   4: invokespecial #3                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7: astore_1
   8: aload_1
   9: ldc           #4                  // String 1
  11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  14: ldc           #4                  // String 1
  16: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  19: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  22: astore_2
  23: aload_2
  24: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/String.intern:()Ljava/lang/String;
  27: astore_3
  28: ldc           #8                  // String 11
```

As the **bytecode**, you can see `new String("1")+new String("1");` is created by using `StringBuilder`

`new           #2                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder`

it's totally a new Object without **String Pool** variable.

and after `s3.intern()`, this method will add current `s3` to the **Memory String Pool** and `8: aload_1`.

and `s4` is trying to load from

`ldc           #8                  // String 11`

so `s3` and `s4` address should equal and result is true.

Comment: Perfect!!!! Your *bytecode* trace hits the spot and explains all of it!!

Comment: Just one question here. What is the way to be followed to get a **bytecode** trace like this?

Comment: I mean, are you using anything other than `javap` ?

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar, Yes I am using `javap`  for see bytecode.

Comment: How does "this method will add current s3 to the Memory String Pool" work? The String "11" is already in the constant pool, due to being used as a literal constant. You can see this with the `javap -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone who use groovy, the addition info is: **the behavior is different**

[image]

Answer (score -3):

s.intern() doesn't change the string s. You should have written:

```
    s = s.intern();
```

Comment: So why does it seem to work for `s3.intern()`?. Please read my comment on the original question.

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar yes, it does. @Robby I guess the compiler evaluates the expression. What I've noticed, is that with `s = s.intern()` and `s3 = s3.intern()`, I obtain true and true.

Comment: But you don't need to reassign `s3` to get `true`, as in OP's example.

Comment: @shmosel no, but the documentation says "Returns a canonical representation for the string object.", so the correct way to use .intern(), is to use the returned value (and when done this way, it behaves as expected). That said, I don't know why the original program behaves the way it does.

Comment: We know it's not the correct use. But that's not the question.