# How does String Intern work ( C# vs Java )?

Tags: java, c#, string-interning

I know that the string interning optimization is in both **C#** and **Java**.

When I try these two codes using Java:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char p[]={'h','e','e','l','l','l','l'}; // Make string from char[] to ensure it's not already interned
    String s1 = new String(p);
    String i1 = s1.intern(); 
    System.out.println(s1== i1); // true
}
```

Code number 2:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char p[]={'h','e','e','l','l','l','l'}; // Make string from char[] to ensure it's not already interned
    String s1 = new String(p);
    String i1 = s1.intern(); 
    System.out.println(s1== i1); // true
    String o = "heellll";
    System.out.println(o== i1); // true
    System.out.println(s1== o); // true
}
```

However, when I try the same two code using C#:

```cs
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] p = { 'h', 'e', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l' }; // Make string from char[] to ensure it's not already interned
    String s1 = new String(p);
    String i1 = string.Intern(s1);
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, i1)); // True
}
```

Code number 2:

```cs
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] p = { 'h', 'e', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'l', 'l' }; // Make string from char[] to ensure it's not already interned
    String s1 = new String(p);
    String i1 = string.Intern(s1);
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, i1)); // False
    String o = "heellll";
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(o, i1)); // True
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(s1, o)); // False
}
```

I expect two different scenarios, and I hope one of these scenarios shows the reason why the output of the C# code (code number 2) is not the same as the output of the Java code (code number 2):

My first expectation: in C#, the CLR checks the string literals before it runs any line in your code, so `String o = "heellll";` is executed before running the code (So `String o = "heellll";` is executed `String s1 = new String(p);` then `"heellll"` is added to the `intern pool` before `s1` so when you execute the line `String i1 = string.Intern(s1);` `s1` is not added but `string.Intern(s1);` returns the reference of `"heellll"`), on the other hand (in Java) the JVM does not check the string literals before run any line in your code.

My second expectation: in C# for the CLR, it is a priority to save references of string literals (the CLR saves `s1` reference (in the line `String i1 = string.Intern(s1);`) but when the CLR finds a string literals that represents the value of a string object (`s1`) (in line `String o = "heellll";`) the CLR replaces `s1` reference ( that is in the intern pool) with that string literals reference, but if the CLR finds a string object that represents the value of another string object, the CLR does nothing), on the other hand (in Java) for the JVM, it is not a priority to save references of string literals.

So, which scenario is the right scenario? If the two scenarios are wrong, what is the reason why the output of the C# code (code number 2) is not the same as the output of the Java code (code number 2)?

Comment: On an earlier question, you @'ed me to answer this one.  I'm not going to answer because questions about string interning of literals are (IMO) pointless.  As I said before, if you compare strings the right way (e.g. don't use `==` for strings in Java), then interning behavior has zero impact on functional behavior.  And the rest is just fragile micro-optimization; i.e. 98% a waste of time.  Leave it to the compiler / runtime ... and spend your time learning useful programming skills.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java JVM well, but as far as .NET is concerned, **your first assumption is mostly correct,** except that no code is executed.

Reworded:

In .Net, the CLR loads the string literals into memory when compiling (JIT), before running any line in that function. So although `String o = "heellll";` is **not** executed before the rest of the code, the `"heellll"` string is already in the Intern pool.

So when you execute the line `String i1 = string.Intern(s1);` s1 is not added because the string is already in the pool, it returns the reference of `"heellll"` instead.

One thing I can categorically state: references are not replace using `string.Intern` unless you replace them yourself.

Comment: is there any source about Java JVM that inform that  " Java JVM does not load the string literals into memory before running any line in that function "  ?

Comment: and when you said " references are not replace using string.Intern unless you replace them yourself. "  is that mean there is a way to replace references ( by myself )   ?

Comment: Meaning you can do `x = string.Intern(x);` but if you do just `string.Intern(x);` it doesn't go and update `x` automatically. I don't know about the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD2**: See @user85421 comments below this post.

**UPD**: I was assuming that JVM checks string pool in string constructor, but actually it doesn't. Actually I don't really understand what is happening here, seems like some weird JVM optimization. Normative documents suggest that string should be loaded to pool on class load (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451183/5647513), but small examples show that it doesn't.

```java
public class MyClass {
    String constantInCtor = "heellll"; // works as expected if this is `static`

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = new String(new char[]{'h','e','e','l','l','l','l'});

        String interned = string.intern(); // <-+
                                           //   | or if I swap this lines 
        String constant = "heellll";       // <-+

        System.out.println(string == interned);   // true, expected false // "heellll" was not interned before string.intern()
        System.out.println(constant == interned); // true
        System.out.println(string == constant);   // true, expected false
    }
}
```

Seems that JVM interns literals on first use.

```cs
// CLR
var newstring = new string(new []{'a','b'});
var interned = string.Intern(newstring); // 
var constant = "ab";

Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(newstring, interned)); // False // "ab" is interned before string.Intern
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(constant, interned)); // True
Console.WriteLine(ReferenceEquals(newstring, constant)); // False
```

---

string interning is performed before execution at class/method load (<s>both JVM</s>(see comments) and CLR). The reason why `object.ReferenceEquals(s1, i1)` returns `false` is that `String` constructor in CLR doesn't check string pool when called and always creates new object.

You probably want to ask -- why it does so? The exact answer is: CLR team decided that way. But it's not very informative, so I will speculate a bit on this topic.

String constructor is used to create strings in runtime, probably from untrusted source (user input), so checking is string interned provides very little benefit (small chance that random string will be in the pool), but hinders every string creation (pool lookup is not free, it's O(n) at least + thread synchronization).

String interning provided by runtime rarely finds good application beside reduced binary size (all duplicate string literals in source code are collapsed into 1). If you are certain that you are going to compare a lot of strings (from trusted source) manually crafted string cache would perform better in all cases (at least it will not contain all the unrelated string from your program and all of it's dependencies). Caching strings from untrusted source leads to unbound heap growth, it can be dealt if you are managing pool by itself, but runtime string pool is append only.

---

Do not use `unsafe`, it's really unsafe (probably even more unsafe than using C/C++ directly instead) and doesn't provide **any** benefits in regular code.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic let me see if i understand the upd that you edited : What you exactly say in the upd is that ( if this is `static` or if I swap this lines the code (the Java code) works as expected ) when you said if this is `static` you meant if i add this line ( `String constantInCtor = "heellll";`  ) to my code (the code in my question) ( but I must add the line outside the `main` function to make the variable (`constantInCtor`) static ) and if we apply what you said " if I swap this lines " the code will change into this code (the code is in the link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfzdN.png

Comment: @f877576 see @user85421 comment regardless class constant pool and string intern pool. By unexpected I meant *unexpected from my strong .NET background* as I only occasionally develop for Android. By making `static String constantInCtor` the first use of literal happens in static field initializer, which happens before call of static method `main`. Sorry for confusion.