# JDK constant for empty String

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no String.Empty in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450604/why-is-there-no-string-empty-in-java)

Is there a JDK constant for an empty String, something like String.EMPTY, equaling ""?  I can't seem to find it.  I would prefer using that rather than "".

Thanks

Comment: Why?  It's not as if using `""` costs any extra memory or anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there isn't. But since the entire world (well, almost) uses Jakarta Commons-Lang, you can, too. Use `StringUtils.EMPTY`: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#EMPTY

Comment: I must not be part of the "entire world".

Comment: Not too late to join us.

Comment: OK @Code-Guru, I edited my response accordingly.

Comment: What if I don't want to join you? =p

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with `""`? It behaves like a constant, it's taken from the string pool and it's really short to write, much shorter than `String.EMPTY`.

Also, if what you need is to test if a string is empty, just do this:

```
myString.isEmpty();
```

**UPDATE**

If the string can be null, better use either [`isEmpty()`](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) or [`isNotBlank()`](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache Common's [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) class.

Comment: There's only one drawback to using `""`: IDE's won't index it so it'd be impossible for you to look for references for that constant (or any string literal, for that matter).

Comment: @Isaac Your IDE has full text search, right?

Comment: What if myString is null? isEmpty isn't static either so you can't do String.isEmpty(myString) - at least not in Java 6.

Comment: @Goyuix the fact that the string could be null was not mentioned in the question. For that requirement, use either `isEmpty()` or `isNotBlank()` from Apache's StringUtils class

Comment: @delnan, full text search isn't semantically identical to code-oriented search. Plus, I was referring to the usage of "obvious" string literals in general, not just the empty string.

Comment: @Isaac It's not equivalent, but close enough in my experience. And it beats trading a clear, obvious string literal for a monstrosity like this. But then again, I'm a Python guy, I'm probably biased :-)

Answer (score 3):

Apache Commons does exactly what you want. It has a constant named StringUtils.EMPTY. If you want to take a look, here is the link to the library: http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out the .isEmpty() function, so I'll go one further.  I wanted tell if a string is Null or Empty or Whitespace (ie spaces and/or tabs).  So I wrote my own method to do it.

```
//Check to see if a string is null or empty
public static boolean stringIsNullOrEmpty(String s)
{
    return (s == null) || (s.isEmpty());
}

//Check to see if a string is null or empty or whitespace
public static boolean stringIsNullOrWhiteSpace(String s)
{
    return (s == null) || (s.trim().isEmpty());
}
```

To use these, you would do something like

```
String myString = "whatever";

if(stringIsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString))
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing in the default JDK that I am aware of. You may need to define your own constant, or import a third party library that has one.

If your intention is to check for empty string you could try the following.

`YOUSTRING.isEmpty();`

However note that isEmpty is not Null safe, and not in all versions of the JDK.

To be null safe, use `"".equals(YOURSTRING);`

However this adds empty string into the HEAP each time you do it. Thus it is best to point to a `public static final`  constant, so that there is only ever one on the heap.

Comment: -1 as this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Isacc good point. Thanks for the correction.