# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, fractions

I'm working on a fraction calculator using `String.split()` to get the terms split.  The inputs are separated by spaces( 1/2 / 1/2)

```
String[] toReturn = new String[6];
result = isInputValid(expression);

toReturn = splitExpression(expression, placeToSplit[0]);
int indexOfUnderscore = toReturn[0].indexOf("_");
result = isInputValid(toReturn[0]);

if(toReturn[5] != null){
    getOperator2(toReturn);
}
```

The error is in the if statement. `toReturn[5]` is out of bounds, because when two terms or less were answered split expression, which uses `String.split()` to split it at the spaces, doesn't create `toReturn[5]`, even when I set values to `toReturn[5]`.  If there is a way to tell if a field in an array exists, that could solve it, or if there is a way to tell how many terms are being put in. My program works for `1/2 + 1/2 * 1/2`, but I haven't figured out how to tell if `toReturn[5]` exists.

Answer (score 5):

Correctly:

```
result = isInputValid(expression);

String[] toReturn = splitExpression(expression, placeToSplit[0]);
int indexOfUnderscore = toReturn[0].indexOf("_");
result = isInputValid(toReturn[0]);

if(toReturn.length>5 && !"".equals(toReturn[5]) ){
    getOperator2(toReturn);
}
```

the `toReturn.length>5` part verifies that the array itself is at least 6 items long. Then you can check if that element is `empty` or not...

Comment: Can't be null, but could be String.Empty

Comment: also remove `String[] toReturn = new String[6]; ` and update `String[] toReturn = splitExpression(expression, placeToSplit[0]);`

Comment: Also I don't get what the `result = isInputValid(expression);` does, because `result` is overwritten without reading... Does it throw an exception is the String is invalid?

Comment: +1 for the solution. However,my code did not compile with String.Empty so I had to add another answer.

Comment: Java doesn't have a String.Empty representation. Some people compares against a `new String()` or a `String s = ""` but actually using `isEmpty()` is OK since it checks if the length of the string is 0. This topic [has been discussed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450604/why-is-there-no-string-empty-in-java) before

Comment: @Gamb: the funny thing is that someone else edited that into my code :) Now I put in the method how I usually check string equality in a null-safe way... (even though this can't be null this time)

Comment: @ppeterka I noticed that in the revision history :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should be like. 
Remove first line ,  `String[] toReturn = new String[6];`

update your third line,

```
String[] toReturn = splitExpression(expression, placeToSplit[0]);
```

And check this condition:

```
if(toReturn.length>5 ){ // use !toReturn[5].isEmpty()  to check the empty string
    getOperator2(toReturn);         
    }
```