# JLabel and JTextField string comparison

Tags: java, string, equals, jlabel, jtextfield

When I use JLabel string comparison with `==` works fine

```
private JLabel someJLabel = new JLabel("some text");
...
System.out.println (someJLabel.getText() == "some text"); // returns true
```

but when I use JTextField

```
private JTextField someJTextField = new JTextField("some text");
...
System.out.println (someJTextField.getText() == "some text"); // returns false
```

I know that if I used `someJTextField.getText().equals("some text");` it would work fine.

So why it works with JLabel but not JTextField

EDIT: yes I know that I should use `.equals` with string, I have read this article http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/ but it's known already that I will use "some text" so it could refer to same string object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JTextField internally copies the string to its modifiable document object to support editing so you don't get back the same string in getText().

Comment: I mean in JLabel setText(t) is like this.text = t; while in JTextField it is like this.getDocument().insertText(t); So t is not preserved. If you take a look at the implementation of setText() method in these classes in source of jdk this will become more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

It's not related to JTextField and JLabel.

JVM uses String pool internally and sometimes == operator works because different strings (in your case "some text") points to the same string in pool.
Look at [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool)

Never compare strings with == !!!

Comment: I guess because label has simple string as it's model (data) inside, but JTextField has Document. So when you creates JTextField("some text") it transform "some text" into it's internal document representation (may be char array or something like this) and when you call someJTextField.getText() it invokes new String(char[]) constructor - so string identity is different from original (it points to another place in heap)

Answer (score 0):

Compare Strings with `.equals(Object obj)`

`==` should mostly be used with only primitive objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit difference in == operator and.equals method.
== operator compares two objects while .equals method compare values in two object.

In your case you are comparing two different object although both may be holding same values. In your case you may use .equals method .This will definitely help!