# Why new keyword not needed for String

Tags: java, string, object, new-operator

I am new in java.

In java, `String` is a `class`.But 
we do not have to use `new` keyword to create an object of class `String` where as `new` is used for creating objects for other classes.

I have heard about Wrapper classes like `Integer`,`Double` which are similar to this.
But `String` is not Wrapper,isn't it?

Actually what is happening when i use

```
     String message = "Hai";
```

??
How it is different from

```
String message = new String("Hai");
```

Here is `message` a reference variable or something else??
Are there other classes which do not require `new` to create object ??

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With the following line you are not creating a new `String` object in the heap but reusing a string literal (if already available):

```
String message = "Hai";
```

`"Hai"` is a string literal in the string literal pool. Since, strings are immutable, they are reusable so they are pooled in the string literal pool by the JVM. And this is the recommended way, because you are reusing it.

But, with the following you are actually creating a new object (in the heap):

```
String message = new String("Hai");
```

`new String("Hai")` is a new `String` object. In this case, even if the literal `"Hai"` was already in the string literal pool, a new object is created. This is not recommended because chances are that you might end with more than one `String` objects with the same value.

Also see this post: [Questions about Java's String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1881922/738746)

> Are there other classes which do not require new to create object ??

Actually, you can not create any object in Java without using the keyword `new`.

e.g.

```
Integer i = 1;
```

Does, not mean that the `Integer` object is created without using `new`. It's just not required for us to use the `new` keyword explicitly. But under the hood, if the `Integer` object with value 1 does not already exist in cache (`Integer` objects are cached by JVM), `new` keyword will be used to create it.

Comment: I think, `Integer` is a Wrapper class for primitive type `int`. but string is **not** primitive,is n't it?

Answer (score 9):

The Java language specification allows for representation of a string as a *literal*. You can consider it a shortcut initialization for a String that has one important side-effect that is different from regular initialization via *new*

String literals are all *interned*, which means that they are constant values stored by the Java runtime and can be shared across multiple classes. For example:

```
class MainClass (
    public String test = "hello";
}

class OtherClass {
   public String another = "hello";

   public OtherClass() {
       MainClass main = new MainClass();
       System.out.println(main.test == another);
   }
}
```

Would print out "true" since, both String instances actually point to the same object. This would not be the case if you initialize the strings via the *new* keyword.

Comment: +1. Nice and succinct. We should mention the Java Language Specification is available for free at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/ if OP wants to really dive in to this.

Answer (score 7):

String and Integer creation are different.

```
String s = "Test";
```

Here the '=' operator is overloaded for string. So is the '+' operator in "some"+"things".
Where as,

```
Integer i = 2;
```

Until Java 5.0 this is compile time error; you cant assign primitive to its wrapper. But from Java 5.0 this is called auto-boxing where primitives are auto promoted to their wrappers wherever required.

```
String h1 = "hi";
```

will be different from

```
String h2 = new String("hi");
```

The reason is that the JVM maintains a string table for all string literals. so there will be an entry in the table for "hi" , say its address is 1000.

But when you explicitly create a string object, new object will be created, say its address is 2000. Now the new object will point to the entry in the string table which is 1000.

Hence when you say

```
h1 == h2
```

it compares

```
1000 == 2000
```

So it is false

Comment: The `=` operator is *NOT* overloaded. Java provides some syntactic sugar for strings, so when you write "Hello, World", you get a reference to a `String` object that represent the given character stream. You are implicitly creating an object (if needed) there, but that doesn't have anythin to do with the `=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

In java
"==" compares the left & right hand sides memory locations(and not the value at that memory location) and therefore in case of

`new String("hai")==new String("hai")`

it returns false.

In case of "Hai"=="Hai", java doesn't allocate separate memory for same string literal therefore here "==" returns true. You can always use equals method to compare values.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why doesn't recommended because of memory, using `new` keyword and creating String object, JVM create 2 object between HEAP and SCP, but using just literal is that JVM creating only SCP. That's why we creating String object, just using literal.