# How many objects are being created?

Tags: java, string, object

Had a simple question around Stringz instance pooling in Java

If I have a situation like this: 
Scenario 1:

```
String s1 = "aaa";  
String s2 = new String("aaa");
```

and then flipped 
Scenario 2:

```
String s1 = new String("aaa");  
String s2 = "aaa";
```

In each case- how many objects are being created in the String Pool and Heap ? 
I assumed both would create an equal number of objects (2 Objects - one single "aaa" for both lines in each scenario in the String pool and one for the new Operator). 
I was told in an iview that this wasn't correct - I'm curious as to what is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Actually, this is the correct explanation:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool

Comment: refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext/63324716#63324716

Answer (score 1):

The String for the literal `"aaa"` is created and pooled when the class is loaded, so only one new String is created when <strike>your two lines are</strike> the code is executed.

To be clear: both examples only create one new String object when they execute. The literal is created the first time a class containing the String "aaa" is used.

```
class FooBar{
  void foo(){
    String s1 = "aaa";//the literal already exists  
    String s2 = new String("aaa");//creates string for s2 
  }
  void bar(){
    String s1 = new String("aaa"); //creates string for s1 
    String s2 = "aaa";//the literal already exists  
  }
}

class Test{

    public void main(String... args){
      ...
      //first time class FooBar used in program, class with literals loaded
      FooBar fb = new FooBar();
      //creates one string object, the literal is already loaded
      fb.bar();
      //also creates one string object, the literal is already loaded
      fb.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be technically right, but could you explain more in detail what exactly happens at which time?

Comment: do you imply in both cases? like Michael said could you elaborate as well?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 1 instance in the heap and 1 in the String pool in either case as you said in your interview.

There are two spaces where Strings can reside: The heap and the perm gen where interned strings are stored.

The String constructor creates a String in the heap. String literals are created in the String pool within the permanent generation. Strings in the heap can be moved to the String pool with the method `String.intern()` which interns the String (that is, determines a reference to an equal String in the pool or creates an equal String there, if there is none yet) and returns a reference to the interned String.

EDIT: To check what I have answered, add `System.out.println(s1 == s2);` as a third line to each example. It will print false in both cases, proving that both objects have different memory addresses.

Comment: vote up for well explained answer