# Is using String considered evil in java programming?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to understand if it is useful to use `String` during programming, there is general notion in our group that using `String` is bad practice and `enum` is way to go but I am not able to find enough reasoning to give in my vote against `String` and would appreciate any thoughts and example on the issue?

**Update:**

I should re-phrase my question to word like under what situation usage of `String` is evil and what alternative `dataType` you should be using for the same.

Comment: Perhaps some more context would be useful... ? Is this really *in general* or specifically with respect to constants or input or... ?

Comment: This is in general while defining variables for your bean.

Comment: Not enough context. A simple question of `String` vs `enum` makes no sense. How do you represent a name with an enum for example?

Comment: enum is usually better for defining the state of an object as it constrains the types allowed.

Comment: What are some of the arguments for using String is a bad practice?

Comment: @hunter: imagine a method that takes as a parameter an object's state. If a String is allowed, then nonsense Strings can be passed in. With an enum there is much tighter constraints on what can be passed in.

Comment: I still think we might be missing context, despite your claim that the question is meant in the very general sense, because obviously we cannot do without Strings for most useful programming tasks, even if that just means putting labels on GUI components, creating URLs, etc.

Comment: See also [primitive obsession](http://books.google.ca/books?id=6jyOUrJBJHAC&pg=PT113&dq=primitive+obsession&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h_6OT5THIMTdggfKq7XqDQ&ved=0CFEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=primitive%20obsession&f=false)

Comment: It is dogma that is evil in computer programming, not language features.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String` is useful and the best way to represent textual data. Strings should **not** be used to represent:

- enumerable, related constants (use `enum`). E.g. no `"cm"`, `"mm"`, `"km"` as units. Use a `Unit` enum with these elements. `Unit.cm`, etc.
- numbers (use `int`, `double`, etc.)
- dates (use `Date`, `Calendar` or joda-time `DateTime`)
- passwords - use `char[]` instead, as strings are handled differently by the JVM and the sensitive information may become accessible to an attacker.
- binary content. If you have a `byte[]`, you should not use a `new String(bytes)` to transfer it - you can loose information that way. Strings *can* represent binary content, if it is encoded - in Base64, Hex, etc.

Comment: And they **pretty much never** be used to represent *any/all of the above at once*. "Stringly typed" code is evil++.

Comment: Saying you should use "enumerations" when "enumerations" are appropriate, is answering the question with the question. The OP seems to be asking where enum might be more appropriate than a string.

Comment: @Spencer Kormos I fixed the wording a few seconds after the initial answer. Now it should be clearer (I will improve a bit more)

Comment: @cHao '"Stringly typed" code is evil' - yeah, like javascript!

Comment: @MartinJames: Psh.  Don't even go there.  :)  We're talking about Java, where variables have types.  Using `String` to bypass the type system is just asking for trouble.  (Even in JS, though, it's better IMO not to have 'numbers' like `"3.0"`.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if

```
...
public enum Settings {
    FAST,SLOW,PRECISE
}
...
if(setting == Settings.FAST) {
...
}
```

is better than

```
...
if("FAST".equals(setting)) {
...
}
...
```

Then the answer is yes, enum is better, because you can compare with == instead of .equals() which probably makes the executable faster and is easier to write, plus you can use switch where with string values you cannot, and with enum you can leverage a good IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse to help you avoid typos that would get past the IDE and the compiler if you are checking for String values instead of your enum Flags.

Comment: You can `switch` on strings as of 1.7.  (Granted, the compiler probably just turns it into an `if`/`else`...but still.)

Comment: Yes, you can use switch with strings in 1.7.  Question, can you build Android Apps with Java 1.7 code yet? (Just wondering)

Comment: I imagine so.  Apparently Android doesn't really run Java -- the dev tools translate the Java classes to Dalvik bytecode -- so as long as the class format hasn't significantly changed, you ought to be able to use any version of Java you want.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.String` is not evil. In fact, it's probably the most commonly used class in java (Disclaimer: I have no data to back that up). However, there are some considerations:

- Crypto. There is one instance when dealing with crypto passwords where char arrays should be preferred over Strings:

> It would seem logical to collect and store the password in an object of type java.lang.String. However, here's the caveat: Objects of type String are immutable, i.e., there are no methods defined that allow you to change (overwrite) or zero out the contents of a String after usage. This feature makes String objects unsuitable for storing security sensitive information such as user passwords. You should always collect and store security sensitive information in a char array instead.

-- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html#PBEEx

- When concatenating Strings, you should probably use `StringBuilder` since `java.lang.String` is immutable and new copies are made for each concatenation.
- When a more specialized class exists, e.g. enums, numbers, dates, etc., prefer it over String.

Answer (score 0):

One unfortunate aspect of using `String` is that prior to JDK 7 it doesn't work in a `switch...case` statement; you must (if using `String`s for this purpose) use `if...else if...else` instead.  And you must test with `.equals()` instead of `==`, and under some situations you may want to use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead.  All of these incline me to prefer `enum` to `String` for such situations.

Comment: Actually, it does work with switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Out of mind and assuming this list is not exhaustive.

Pros:
[Java SE 7: String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - The String class is immutable so Strings can be shared (this also implies thread safety).
[String pool in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool) - Strings are pooled so it is efficient when re-using them.

Cons:
Concat operations are not efficient when using `+` for multiple Strings.
It is better to use a `StringBuilder` or a `StringBuffer` (thread-safe) or `Ropes`.
See this: [IBM: Ropes](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ropes/)

Answer (score 0):

String is not evil in and of itself.

I think the harm comes when you use it as your primary abstraction.  You see it in code where there are lots of primitives (e.g. Strings, ints, arrays, data structures) that are obviously related, but are scattered throughout code.

A better solution in those cases is to encapsulate data items that belong together into a sensible object.