# How many string objects will be created by JVM version 1.6

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions about Java's String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool)

Recently I read a java article and found the following statement "improved the String pooling technology in java 6 onward". One of the example that they have mentioned as follows

```
String one = "one";
String two = new String("one");
```

Number of objects created by above example is = 1

Here I am little confused, even though we are using the `new` keyword how come it will not create a new object and uses the object created in the string pool.

Please clarify me.

Comment: This creates one object, just the `new String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing one == two should help determining how many objects got created.

Comment: you are correct, it is actually creating two objects. `one == two` returned `false`.