# String Pool in the JVM

Tags: java, string

I am really confused in string pooling

how many objects will create in this situation

```
String a=new String("Hi"); //1
String b=new String("Hi"); //2
String c="hi"; //3
```

If in case of 2nd and 3rd string one object is being created, then why it is returning FALSE in case of (a==b)....

Comment: This has been asked so many times before ... For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536670/how-many-string-objects-will-be-created-by-jvm-version-1-6. This one has even better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool

Answer (score 4):

> why it is returning FALSE in case of (a==b)

Because you're using `new String` thus getting new object references for those `String`s.

Note that changing the code to

```
String a = "Hi"; //1
String b = "Hi"; //2
```

will make `System.out.println(a == b);` printing `true`.

Further explanation: [The String Pool](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/187631-the-string-pool/)

Comment: @JoachimSauer right, made a test to verify my statement (got confused with `Integer` pooling). Removed that part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, for non-primitive types, the `==` operator compares references, not values.

If you create a bunch of equivalent String literals, like:

```
String sLit1 = "test";
String sLit2 = "test";
```

`(sLit1 == sLit2)` will be `true`, since Java doesn't allocate new memory for each new String literal, it just points them all to the same location in memory.  However, when you create a String object:

```
String sObj = new String("test")
```

Java always creates a new object, which occupies a new location in memory.  So `sLit1 == sObj` will always be `false`.

Which means that `==` yields `true` if and only if the two arguments refer to the same object.  To compare strings, use `equals` method, as in `(sObj.equals(sLit1))`.

Comment: Thanx , but one more thing, if i am using inturn() method, it is returning true in case of new keyword also

Comment: Here you go, [java.lang.String.intern()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091045/is-it-good-practice-to-use-java-lang-string-intern).

Comment: Also, since you're also a new user, you should check out the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Its not one object ,You are creating Strings using new keyword,so jvm creates these Strings in Heap so both objects address is different.

And == check objects address thats why it is returning false.

and in case of String c="hi";

This is not creating using new so these literals creates in String pool.and there is interning process by jvm on these literals.

if there is one more String d="hi";  then c==d will return true.

Comment: what is use of compareTo in java String?? I am unable to understand its output

Comment: compareTo is method of Comparable interface which is implemented by String class.and is used to compare two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
String c = "Hi";
```

will create the string literal in String literal pool which is a separate memory provided for string literals in java. 
When you write

```
String c = "Hi";
String d = "Hi";
```

They will refer to the same literal in string constant pool. 
and == operator checks wheter reference variables refer to the same object

Hence, c == d will return true.