# In Java, does `String s = "lol";` create two objects?

Tags: java, string

I have heard that two objects are created when you execute `String s = new String("lol");`. One object is created for the string constant pool and one for `s` on the heap.

So, are 2 objects created when we execute the following? `String s = "lol";` Is the object creation the same?

Edit:

how many objects are created by :
`String s1 = new String("lol1");`

and how many by :
`String s2 = "lol2";`

Comment: Actually, "lol" in the constant pool is created when the first String literal for that value is loaded in any class -- could be a class loaded 10 minutes ago.  And simply assigning an object reference value to an object reference variable does not create any objects.

Comment: Related (but to a different question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855170/when-should-we-use-intern-method-of-string-on-string-constants also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672402/javaliteral-strings?rq=1

Comment: No. One is a literal value, and one is an object.

Comment: @AlexJohnson - A String literal is an object.

Comment: @HotLicks Indeed, which is why, until Java gets a null coalescing operator like C#'s `??`, `"expectedValue".equals(someStringVariableThatMayBeNull)` is such a useful construct in the real world. :)

Comment: @HotLicks Not just a grammar production? ;-)

Comment: @HotLicks Touche, nice catch. I was meaning the object as a string object, and the other as just a string. Poor choice of words using literal.

Comment: What is "just a string" (but presumably not an "object") in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, with `String s = "lol";`, <s>only one object is created</s>.  With every string literal, a `String` object is created and placed in the string pool.  Here, `s` just refers to that pooled string.  When you say `s = new String("lol")`, the string literal is created and pooled, and another string is allocated and assigned to `s`, which is a different, yet `equal`, string.

**UPDATE**

I had forgotten about the `char[]` that is used internally by a `String` object.

```
String s1 = "lol";
```

2 objects are created, the `char[]` that holds `{'l', 'o', 'l'}` and the `String` object that references it internally.  It's interned in the string pool.

```
String s2 = new String("lol");
```

3 objects are created.  First, the string literal: 2 objects are created, the `char[]` that holds `{'l', 'o', 'l'}` and the `String` object that references it.  It's interned in the string pool as before.  Then, the new `String` object that gets assigned to `s2`: A new `String` is created, but it references the same char array as the original string.  Two `String` objects, and one `char[]` object.  <sub>(The `String(String)` constructor may make a copy of the `char[]` in the circumstance that the original string's array's length is somehow greater than its `count`, but that doesn't appear to be the case here.)</sub>

- [Grepcode for `java.lang.String(String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Actually, zero objects created, if the earlier statement referencing "lol" is still in the class.  There is (at most) only one representation of the literal value "lol" anywhere in the entire JVM.

Comment: @HotLicks I had interpreted the question to mean that the two statements were different examples, not two lines in the same program.

Comment: You would not get just one, a `String` wraps a `char[]`  so there is likely to be two, or none.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - A String doesn't necessarily wrap a `char[]`.

Comment: Ok one follow up question : why are Two String objects created in case of `String s2 = new String("lol");` ?

Comment: One for the string literal, and one for the new `String` object created by `new`.

Comment: @HotLicks How would describe the relationship between the `String` and the `char[]` in it? See the `String(int offset, int count, char value[])` constructor http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%29

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Who says there has to be a `char[]` in it?  Maybe in that particular implementation, but there's nothing in the spec that requires it.  The iSeries "classic" JVM didn't have a `char[]` in most Strings.  Using a `char[]` inside String is a major performance hit.

Comment: @HotLicks Unless you are talking about how the JVM usually works there is no actual requirement to create an object and it could allocate on the stack or optimise it away completely.  OpenJDK, which is the reference implementation for the JVM, uses a `char[]` and you can reasonably expect most JVMs will also.

Comment: You can't legally optimize away the creation of an object.  And an object created on the stack is still an object.  (And the meaning of "reference implementation" is "slow".)

Answer (score 3):

`"lol"` is a `String` literal - when you reference it in your code, you force Java to create this object. The second object you're seeing is when you explicitly call `String`'s constructor with the `new` operator. Assigning these values to other variables does not create additional objects.

Comment: It should be noted that only one instance of "lol" is created for the life of the JVM, regardless of how many classes use the literal how many times.  `new String`, however, creates a new object every time it executes.