# overload final string is possible?

Tags: java, overloading

I created a class with 2 method, one can take 3 parameter while another one can take 4.. all the parameters declared as final..

then I wrote this

```
    if (b == "Select") {
        myobj.print(a, b, c, d);
    } else {
        myobj.print(a, b, c);
    }
```

it doesn't work..

Comment: First and foremost:  You're using `==` instead of `.equals("Select")`.  Second, could you clarify your question a little bit more?  You can't overload the `String` class - it's final.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What is `myobj`?  What is the signature for `myobj.print`?

Comment: Use "Select".equals(b) instead of ==.
Look at this reference for Java String pool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` are immutable, you can't change them.

Unless you are using `String` literals, you should always use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `==` to compare `Strings/objects`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an overload of a method with an extra String argument is:

- possible,
- valid Java, and
- it works.

My money is on the theory that your problem is nothing to do with overloading, and actually due to your mistake of using `==` to test if two strings are equal.