# Is a valid scenario for assigning string from string pool?

Tags: java

I have been given the following condition?

```
String A="a";
String B="b";
String c="a"+"b";
```

My question is is the String c created newly or is assigned from the string pool the value "a" and "b" and total how many strings are formed according to above question?

Comment: -1 : There are already so many answers about string pool that I wonder how you can ask this one, unless you haven't searched at all on SO.

Comment: Here is a possible duplicate: [string pool behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490043/string-pool-behavior)

Comment: I know its their and even I read it several times, but was bit confused while going through one article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes c is created newly.  Strings in Java are effectively [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java) (i.e. once created, they never change).  One of the consequences of this is that, whenever you do a manipulation that changes a string, you get back a new, different object.

So in your example, 3 strings are created.

Answer (score 0):

Take these two `String` objects:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";
String c = "a" + "b";
String d = "ab";
```

The compiler creates and pools three `String` objects. A line by line explanation follows.

- **Line 1:** One `String` object is pooled for `"a"`
- **Line 2:** One `String` object is pooled for `"b"`
- **Line 3:** `"a" + "b"` is computer at compile time and treated as a literal. Therefore, one `String` object is pooled for `"ab"`
- **Line 4:** `"ab"` is already in the pool

Following the same guidelines, **your example produces 3 String objects.**