# How should I declare strings?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Questions about Java’s String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool)

What's the difference between the two ways of declaring strings in Java?

```
String se1 = "java";
String se2 = "java";
System.out.println(se1 == se2); // output true

String str1 = new String("OKAY");
String str2 = new String("OKAY");
System.out.println(str1 == str2); // output false
```

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked many times already. Please use search.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus

Comment: "OKAY" was interned. But new String("OKAY") creates a **new** String object with the same chars as the interned "OKAY".

Comment: Also read: [How do I compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Never use new String(String) like that.

Comment: new String("foo") makes *two* Strings.  Both .equals("foo"); they contain equivalent characters.  You shouldn't use that way, because it's inefficient to make the second String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `==` when comparing objects including strings. Generally `==` compares *references*, so it return `true` only of same objects. You should use `equals()` method instead: `str1.equals(str2)`

It occasionally works for you in first case because java caches string constants, so `"java"` in both cases is represented by same instance of String.

Answer (score 2):

`==` on objects compares by reference. The first pair of strings was considered equal due to a feature called internalization. To compare strings for content equality, use

```
s1.compareTo(s2) == 0
```

or

```
s1.equals(s2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's only one instance of string constants, e.g., `"ohai"`, so `==` will work.

New `String` objects are just that, new objects, which may be created from another string's value.

Strings should almost always be compared with `.equals`, e.g.

```
str1.equals(str2);
```

This compares string *values*, not references.

Answer (score 1):

In first case you have declared **se1** and **se2** as **String literals**. So you can use **==** operator to compare two **Strings**.

But in later case **str1** and **str2** are **String objects** and hence compairing through == operators fails. To compare two objects you should use **equals** method.