# How many object will be created in the String Constant Pool and heap

Tags: java, string, object, heap-memory, string-pool

How many object will be created in the String Constant Pool and heap for the following code :

```
String s1 = "Stack";  
String s2 = s1 + " Overflow";
```

As per my knowledge all literals are created in the String Constant pool, But the string concat operator internally uses StringBuffer to append the strings , so will an object be created in Heap also ?

Comment: As Strings are **Immutable** any appending to the existing string would result in creation of a new string with the previous value appended with the new. So its better to use a **StringBuilder**.

Comment: To your original question, there will be three strings created, Stack, Overflow and Stack Overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Questions about Java's String pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool)

Comment: @saifahmad your suggestion doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @akshaya pandey  Will any object be created in heap ?.. Because concat operator '+' internally uses StringBuffer to append the strings ..

Comment: Please go through the following link. There is a great explanation of string pools and interns along with examples and images. This is a nice tutorial to clear the concepts http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/05/string-pool-string-literal-pool-string.html

Answer (score 0):

There two Objects will be created in String Constant Pool. As `String s2 = s1 + " Overflow";` At compile time, compiler will append these two strings and only one object will be created in String Constant Pool and other object is `s1`.

```
package testPackage;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Stack";  
        String s2 = s1 + " Overflow";
        System.out.println(s1 == "Stack");
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
        System.out.println(s2 == "Stack Overflow");
    }
}
```

produces the output:

```
true
false
false
```

Comment: What about the literal " Overflow" ? Will it not be created in the String constant pool ?

Comment: No, it will not be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1 = "Stack";
```

`"Stack"` will be in the String Constant pool.

```
String s2 = s1 + " Overflow";
```

Internally `+ operator` uses `StringBuilder` for concatenating strings.

So internal implementation  `String s2 = s1 + " Overflow";` will be

```
String str = new StringBuilder(s1).append("Overflow").toString();
```

Here since it is `new StringBuilder(str)` so the `StringBuilder` object will be created in `the Heap`. Lets look into `StringBuilder(String str)` constructor

```
public StringBuilder(String str) {
    super(str.length() + 16);
    append(str);
}
```

and `super(int capacity)` constructor

```
AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) {
    value = new char[capacity];
}
```

Here we can see that the `StringBuilder(String str)` constructor just creating a `char[] array` and calling `append(String str)` method.

If we look at the implementation of `append(String str)` method of `StringBuilder` we can see that the `append(String str)` method is just playing with a `char[] array` and it's not creating any new object or array.

```
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

and the implementation of `super.append(String str)` is

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(String str) {
    if (str == null) str = "null";
    int len = str.length();
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + len);
    str.getChars(0, len, value, count);
    count += len;
    return this;
}
```

At the end lets look at the `toString()` method `StringBuilder` class.

```
public String toString() {
    // Create a copy, don't share the array
    return new String(value, 0, count);
}
```

The `toString()` method of `StringBuilder` is returning a **`new String`** which will be definitely in the `Heap` since it is created with `new String(...)`;

The above explanation says that **`The StringBuilder will only create a new string when toString() is called on it. Until then, it maintains an char[] array of all the elements added to it.`**

***`So, the conclusion is "Stack" will be in the String Constant pool and s1 + " Overflow" i.e Stack overflow will be in the Heap.`***

Comment: What about the literal " Overflow"  ? It will also be created in String Constant pool ??

Comment: It will be there in the char[] array of StringBuilder. It wont be there in String Constant pool.