# Is the char literal '\"' the same as '"' ?(backslash-doublequote vs only-doublequote)

Tags: java, string, char, escaping

Is there's any difference between `char` literals `'\"'` and `'"'` ?

Comment: Ummm ... it would have taken 30 seconds to test it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutely no difference. The two `char` are `==`.

```
System.out.println('\"' == '"'); // prints "true"
```

Strictly speaking it's not necessary to escape a double quote in a `char` literal, but it doesn't change this fact that `\"` denotes the double quote character `\u0022`.

#### References

- [JLS 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6)

---

#### `String` analog

We also have the analogous situation for `String` literals:

```
System.out.println("\'".equals("'")); // prints "true"
```

In fact, we can even go a step further and use `==` for reference equality:

```
System.out.println("\'" == "'"); // prints "true"
```

The second snippet proves that the two string literals are *really* equal, and therefore subject to string interning at compile-time.

#### References

- [JLS 3.10.5 String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5)

  > String literals --or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions-- are *"interned"* so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

#### Related questions

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- [Java `String.equals` versus `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)
- [Where do Java and .NET string literals reside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372547/where-do-java-and-net-string-literals-reside)
- [When `“” == s` is `false` but `“”.equals( s )` is `true`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111296/when-s-is-false-but-equals-s-is-true)

---

#### Summary

- A single-quote in a `char` literal *MUST* be escaped

  - Because `char` literal is quoted in single-quotes
- A double-quote in a `String` literal *MUST* be escaped

  - Because `String` literal is quoted in double-quotes
- It doesn't hurt to escape, even when it's not necessary

  - Go with what's most readable