# Having trouble with Splitting text

Tags: java, split

Here's the code I'm using :

```
public class splitText {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "I lost my Phone. I shouldn't drive home alone";
    String[] result = x.split(".");
    for (String i : result) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

Compiles perfectly, but nothing happens at runtime. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Compiles perfectly, but nothing happens at runtime." - This may break your heart but just because it compiles, doesn't mean it work.

Comment: Aww no.. please tell me you're joking. :P

Comment: the computer (almost) always does exactly what you *told* him to do... not necessarily what you *want* him to do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`String.split(String regex)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a regular-expression pattern. It just so happens that `.` in regex is a metacharacter that matches (almost) any character, hence why `split(".")` doesn't work the way you expected.

You can escape the `.` by preceding it with a backslash. As a Java string literal, this is `"\\."`. The `\` is doubled because `\` itself is a Java escape character. `"\\."` is a `String` of length 2, containing a backslash and a period.

If you're given an arbitrary `String` that is to be matched literally (or if you just don't care to escape them yourself), you can use [`Pattern.quote`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). It'll make a pattern to literally match a given `String`.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

---

This is provided for educational purposes only:

```
    String text =
        "Wait a minute... what?!? Oh yeah! This is awesome!!";

    for (String part : text.split("(?<=[.?!]) ")) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
```

This prints:

```
Wait a minute...
what?!?
Oh yeah!
This is awesome!!
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

#### Related questions

- [How does the regular expression `(?<=#)[^#]+(?=#)` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092797/how-does-the-regular-expression-work/)

Comment: ""\\." is a String of length 2, containing a backslash and a period."  

Umm.. I didn't get that. Can anyone re-explain it?

Comment: @MoonStruckHorrors: A `String s = "\n";` contains one character, the newline character. `"\t"` contains a tab. `"\\"` contains a backslash. `"\""` contains a double quote. This is called an escape sequence. So since `"\\"` contains a backslash, `"\\."` contains a backslash and a period. You can print it out and check its `length()` to confirm. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224337/doubt-about-java-char/

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't that mean it'll split the string at `\.` and not `.` ?

Comment: @MoonStruck: the regular expression pattern `\.` matches a literal period. The regular expression pattern `.` matches (almost) any character. So the pattern `a.b` matches strings like `"axb"`, `"a!b"`, etc. The pattern `a\.b` matches only `"a.b"`.

Answer (score 5):

String.split uses a regex, so dot (.) means "anything".
You need to escape the dot

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "I lost my Phone. I shouldn't drive home alone";
    String[] result = x.split("\\.");
    for (String i : result) {
        System.out.println(i.trim());
    }
}
```

gives :

```
I lost my Phone
I shouldn't drive home alone
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
String [] result = x.split("\\.");
```

Split takes in a [pattern](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/), not a character to split on.  The "." is treated special in patterns.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use regex, you can use the Splitter of guava lib

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html

```
 String x = "I lost my Phone. I shouldn't drive home alone";
 Splitter.on('.').trimResults().split(x)
```

moreover, the result is an Iterable, not an array