# How to replace a special character with single slash

Tags: java

I have a question about strings in Java. Let's say, I have a string like so:

```
String str = "The . startup trace ?state is info?";
```

As the string contains the special character like `"?"` I need the string to be replaced with `"\?"` as per my requirement. How do I replace special characters with `"\"`? I tried the following way.

```
str.replace("?","\?");
```

But it gives a compilation error. Then I tried the following:

```
str.replace("?","\\?");
```

When I do this it replaces the special characters with  `"\\"`. But when I print the string, it prints with single slash. I thought it is taking single slash only but when I debugged I found that the variable is taking `"\\"`.

Can anyone suggest how to replace the special characters with single slash (`"\"`)?

Comment: Please address people's confusion with your question. Give multiple examples of before and after that covers all of your expectations.

Answer (score 5):

#### On escape sequences

A declaration like:

```
String s = "\\";
```

defines a string containing a single backslash. That is, `s.length() == 1`.

This is because `\` is a Java escape character for `String` and `char` literals. Here are some other examples:

- `"\n"` is a `String` of length 1 containing the newline character
- `"\t"` is a `String` of length 1 containing the tab character
- `"\""` is a `String` of length 1 containing the double quote character
- `"\/"` contains an invalid escape sequence, and therefore is not a valid `String` literal

  - it causes compilation error

Naturally you can combine escape sequences with normal unescaped characters in a `String` literal:

```
System.out.println("\"Hey\\\nHow\tare you?");
```

The above prints (tab spacing may vary):

```
"Hey\
How are you?
```

#### References

- [JLS 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6)

#### See also

- [Is the char literal `'\"'` the same as `'"'` ?(backslash-doublequote vs only-doublequote)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224337/is-the-char-literal-the-same-as-backslash-doublequote-vs-only-doublequ/)

---

#### Back to the problem

Your problem definition is very vague, but the following snippet works as it should:

```
System.out.println("How are you? Really??? Awesome!".replace("?", "\\?"));
```

The above snippet replaces `?` with `\?`, and thus prints:

```
How are you\? Really\?\?\? Awesome!
```

If instead you want to replace a `char` with another `char`, then there's also an overload for that:

```
System.out.println("How are you? Really??? Awesome!".replace('?', '\\'));
```

The above snippet replaces `?` with `\`, and thus prints:

```
How are you\ Really\\\ Awesome!
```

#### `String` API links

- [`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

  - Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal `target` sequence with the specified literal `replacement` sequence.
- [`replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

  - Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of `oldChar` in this string with `newChar`.

---

#### On how regex complicates things

If you're using `replaceAll` or any other regex-based methods, then things becomes somewhat more complicated. It can be greatly simplified if you understand some basic rules.

- Regex patterns in Java is given as `String` values
- Metacharacters (such as `?` and `.`) have special meanings, and may need to be escaped by preceding with a backslash to be matched literally
- The backslash is also a special character in replacement `String` values

The above factors can lead to the need for numerous backslashes in patterns and replacement strings in a Java source code.

It doesn't look like you need regex for this problem, but here's a simple example to show what it can do:

```
    System.out.println(
        "Who you gonna call? GHOSTBUSTERS!!!"
            .replaceAll("[?!]+", "<$0>")
    );
```

The above prints:

```
Who you gonna call<?> GHOSTBUSTERS<!!!>
```

The pattern `[?!]+` matches one-or-more (`+`) of any characters in the character class `[...]` definition (which contains a `?` and `!` in this case). The replacement string `<$0>` essentially puts the entire match `$0` within angled brackets.

#### Related questions

- [Having trouble with Splitting text.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265132/having-trouble-with-splitting-text/) - discusses common mistakes like `split(".")` and `split("|")`

#### Regular expressions references

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to replace `?` with `\?`, there are 2 possibilities: `replace` and `replaceAll` (for regular expressions):

```
str.replace("?", "\\?")

str.replaceAll("\\?","\\\\?");
```

The result is `"The . startup trace \?state is info\?"`

If you want to replace `?` with `\`, just remove the `?` character from the second argument.

Comment: Aren't you on [Java 1.5](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) yet? **Edit:** sorry, your edit still doesn't explain the *actual* question :)

Comment: @BalusC: I edited my answer again. I didn't understand exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: The OP was wondering why he would need a double backslash to match a single backslash. Polygenelubricants has explained it nicely.

Comment: He also asks *'Can anyone suggest how to...'*

Answer (score 0):

> But when I print the string, it prints
>   with single slash.

Good. That's exactly what you want, isn't it?

There are two simple rules:

1. A backslash inside a String literal has to be specified as two to satisfy the compiler, i.e. "\". Otherwise it is taken as a special-character escape.
2. A backslash in a regular expresion has to be specified as two to satisfy regex, otherwise it is taken as a *regex* escape. Because of (1) this means you have to write 2x2=4 of them:"\\\\" (and because of the forum software I actually had to write 8!).

Answer (score 0):

```
        String str="\\";
        str=str.replace(str,"\\\\");
        System.out.println("New String="+str);
```

**Out put:- New String=\**

In java `"\\"` treat as `"\"`. So, the above code replace a `"\"` single slash into `"\\"`.