# How to convert an Int to a String of a given length with leading zeros to align?

Tags: string, scala, formatting, int

How can I convert an `Int` to a 7-character long `String`, so that `123` is turned into `"0000123"`?

Answer (score 269, accepted):

The Java library has pretty good (as in excellent) [number formatting support](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) which is accessible from [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) enriched String class:

```
scala> "%07d".format(123)
res5: String = 0000123

scala> "%07d".formatLocal(java.util.Locale.US, 123)
res6: String = 0000123
```

*Edit post Scala 2.10*: as suggested by fommil, from 2.10 on, there is also a formatting string interpolator (does not support localisation):

```
val expr = 123
f"$expr%07d"
f"${expr}%07d"
```

**Edit Apr 2019:**

- If you want leading spaces, and not zero, just leave out the `0` from the format specifier. In the above case, it'd be `f"$expr%7d"`.Tested in 2.12.8 REPL. No need to do the string replacement as suggested in a comment, or even put an explicit space in front of `7` as suggested in another comment.
- If the length is variable, `s"%${len}d".format("123")`

Comment: Ben, dhg, thanks for the upvotes, you guys are a tough crowd though! I think we can still learn something from the other answers, and the voting system takes care of which answer is relevant.

Comment: you don't need to be this explicit, you can write `f"$a%07d"` (if you have a `val`/`var` `a` in scope).

Comment: @fommil, indeed, that wasn't there yet when I posted the initial answer, but I would also use the f interpolator now that it exists.

Comment: If you want **leading *spaces*** instead of *leading zeros* then you can use `regex` `string.replaceAll("\\G0", " ")` to replace leading zeros with spaces as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3341868/3679900)

Comment: If you want **leading spaces** instead of *leading zeros* then use `"% 7d".format(123)`.

Answer (score 51):

**Short answer:**

```
"1234".reverse.padTo(7, '0').reverse
```

**Long answer:**

Scala [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html) (which contains a nice set of methods that Scala string objects have because of implicit conversions) has a `padTo` method, which appends a certain amount of characters to your string. For example:

```
"aloha".padTo(10,'a')
```

Will return "alohaaaaaa". Note the element type of a String is a Char, hence the single quotes around the `'a'`.

Your problem is a bit different since you need to **prepend** characters instead of **appending** them. That's why you need to reverse the string, append the fill-up characters (you would be prepending them now since the string is reversed), and then reverse the whole thing again to get the final result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Use .mkString to turn back into a string

Comment: or use the character 'a'

Answer (score 35):

The `padding` is denoted by `%02d` for `0` to be prefixed to make the length `2`:

```
scala> val i = 9 
i: Int = 9

scala> val paddedVal = f"${num}%02d"
paddedVal: String = 09

scala> println(paddedVal)             
09
```

Comment: In this line `val paddedVal = f"${num}%02d"` should be change `num` for `i`

Comment: `f"$num%02d"` (no brackets neeeded here)

Answer (score 10):

huynhjl beat me to the right answer, so here's an alternative:

```
"0000000" + 123 takeRight 7
```

Comment: This will fail for numbers greater than 10M: `"0000000" + Int.MaxValue takeRight 7` => `7483647`. While "technically" correct by the literal interpretation of the question, it's unlikely that the reader doesn't want the padded number to extend beyond 7 digits if the number is that large.

Comment: Well you could say this solution is better because at least the digits are still correctly aligned in that particular case, unlike the accepted solution. The whole point of the question is to make the digits align properly.

Answer (score 7):

```
def leftPad(s: String, len: Int, elem: Char): String = {
 elem.toString * (len - s.length()) + s
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case this Q&A becomes the canonical compendium,

```
scala> import java.text._
import java.text._

scala> NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance.asInstanceOf[DecimalFormat]
res0: java.text.DecimalFormat = java.text.DecimalFormat@674dc

scala> .applyPattern("0000000")

scala> res0.format(123)
res2: String = 0000123
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to deal with negative numbers? If not, I would just do

```
def str(i: Int) = (i % 10000000 + 10000000).toString.substring(1)
```

or

```
def str(i: Int) = { val f = "000000" + i; f.substring(f.length() - 7) }
```

Otherwise, you can use `NumberFormat`:

```
val nf = java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(java.util.Locale.US)
nf.setMinimumIntegerDigits(7)
nf.setGroupingUsed(false)
nf.format(-123)
```

Answer (score 0):

For String use:

```
def completeTo10Digits(entity: String): String = {
    val zerosToAdd = (1 to (10 - entity.length)).map(_ => "0").mkString
    zerosToAdd + entity
  }
```