# How to pad array with zeros in scala

Tags: playframework

I am trying to pad array elements with zero if they are less 10. That is if I have  elements in an array 1,2,12 I want to print 01,02,12.I am trying to do this in the scala template in the playframework. So what I tried now was to use if and else statemnts in scala to see if the element is less than 10 and then pad a zero.

```
@for(element <- myarray){
        @if(element.getValue < 10){@element} else{@element}

    }
```

myarray is a Uint8 array which is defined by me and getValue is function in the UINT8 class. Hpowever it keeps telling me that `not found: value element`. Is there any other way out to just pad with 0's for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that Play's view is also a Scala function, so you can easily perform operations directly in the code, for an example use common way for formatting integer to string with **leading zeros** (as found in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8131682/1066240)):

```
@for(i <- 1 to 1000){
    @("%04d".format(i))<br>
}
```

Comment: Yep. I am new to Scala and I find it difficult to use currently since I have never learnt it before