# Scala String interpolation with Format, how to change locale?

Tags: string, scala, string-interpolation

When doing format string interpolation in Sweden I get a comma instead of a dot when creating strings with decimal numbers:

```
scala> val a = 5.010
a: Double = 5.01

scala> val a = 5.0101
a: Double = 5.0101

scala> f"$a%.2f"
res0: String = 5,01
```

My question is, how do I set the format so that I get the result `5.01`? I would like to be able to set the locale only for that String, i.e. so that I don't change the locale for the whole environment.

Cheers,

Johan

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the same [Java library number formatting support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)  accessible 
from [`StringOps` enriched String class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps), you could specify another locale just for that output:

```
"%.2f".formatLocal(java.util.Locale.US, a)
```

(as described in "[How to convert an Int to a String of a given length with leading zeros to align?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8131291/6309)")

The Scala way would be to use the [string f interpolator](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) (Scala 2.10+), as in the OP's question, but it is using the "current locale", without offering an easy way to set that locale to a different one just for one call.

Comment: Should be `a`, not `$a`

Comment: Thank you, is there any other way, I mean still using the nice Scala way and not the Java way? Cheers, otherwise I'll just accept you.

Answer (score 4):

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US)
println(f"$a%.2f")
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.