# Force specific decimal separator using the f string interpolator in Scala

Tags: string, scala, string-interpolation, scala-2.11

I'm trying to compose a formatted string that should look like this:

> A bottle of vodka costs x.yz rubles.

where x.yz is an arbitrary Double value rounded to 2 decimal signs.

To achieve this, I use string interpolation with printf syntax:

```
val cost = 2.56
val str = f"A bottle of vodka costs $cost%.2f rubles."
```

Unfortunately, on a machine with Russian locale, the snippet above yields a result that is a bit different from what I want to achieve:

> str: String = A bottle of vodka costs **2,56** rubles.

This is understandable (the Java formatter used by f interpolator applies the locale-specific decimal separator, as outlined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)), but I still want to use decimal dot instead of comma.

I'm aware of a possible workaround – using the `formatLocal()` method with explicitly set locale:

```
 val str = "A bottle of vodka costs %.2f  rubles.".formatLocal(java.util.Locale.US, cost)
```

but it does not strike me as a particularly Scalaesque way of doing things.

So my question is this: is it possible to format a string with a specific decimal separator using only f interpolation, without any extraneous method calls?

Comment: Related: [*the string `f` interpolator is using the "current locale", without offering an easy way to set that locale to a different one just for one call.*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24780052/scala-string-interpolation-with-format-how-to-change-locale)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! Notice, however, that my question is limited to using an arbitrary decimal separator; I'm not interested in changing locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment `f` interpolator does not support locales nor custom separators (see `macro_StringInterpolation_f.scala` / `FastTrack.scala`).

Comment: From what I've gleaned from [Scala source code on GitHub](https://github.com/scala/scala), this seems true (if a tad disappointing). Thanks!