# how can I use padTo for padding to the left?

Tags: java, scala, pad

I have a number, I want to pad this number with zero's in the beginning if the digits are less that 9 digits.

currently if I have a number lets say:

```
val num = "123"
```

if I use `padTo(9,"0")` I will get `"123000000"` but I want `"000000123"`...

what is the best solution for this?

would be better to get the solution in scala

thanks

Comment: its not duplicate cause my number is string and not an int @Tunaki

Comment: There are other answers that cover this case, like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/8131372/1743880

Comment: this is not a good solution, using revers on the string and then another revers its a hack @Tunaki

Comment: How about the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388461/how-can-i-pad-a-string-in-java): `String.format("%9s", "123").replace(' ', '0');` ? Or do you consider that to also be a hack?